# How to export JavaScript Json info to csv (on client side)?

Tags: javascript, json, csv

from array info to csv :

```
<script>

    function downloadCsv() {
        var data = arrCsvData;
        var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
        data.forEach(function(infoArray, index) {

            dataString = infoArray.join(",");
            csvContent += index < data.length ? dataString + "\n" : dataString;

        });

        var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
        link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");

        link.click();
    }

</script>
```

Similarly how can i export javascript json info to csv (on client side)??

Comment: here 'arrCsvData' is an array of data..

Comment: This seems to be covered in this stackoverflow question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable)

Answer (score -1):

Here is how we can download json array of array to cdv data format :

```
function downloadCsv() {
            var data = arrCsvData;
            var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";

                for (var key in data) {
                  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    data[key].unshift([key,""]);
                    for(var index=0;index<data[key].length;index++){
                        var elementArray = data[key][index];
                        data[key][index] = elementArray.join(",");
                    }
                    csvContent += data[key].join("\n");
                  }
                  csvContent += "\n";
                }
            var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
            link.setAttribute("download", "graphData.csv");

            link.click();
        }
```

It worked for me :)

Answer (score -1):

I made my own implementation of this exact problem.

It translates a JSON array of JSON objects to a CSV file readable in Office 365 Excel.

I use it to convert a table for work into a excel sheet.

```
    var jsonData = [
        {
            "Object": "Object",
            "AnotherObject": "AnotherValue"
        },
        {
            "Object": "SecondObject",
            "AnotherObject": "SecondValue"
        }
    ];
    WriteCSV(jsonData);
```

Would give this in Excel:

[Screenshot Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGKVC.png)

[Github page](https://github.com/teunw/JSON-to-CSV-converter/blob/master/jsonToExcelCsv.js)