# How to export csv file and send the same attachment via email in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, export-to-csv

I'm new to Ionic2.There is no document provided for converting JSON to csv.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON to CSV format and store in a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable)