# How to make json array downloaded in csv format in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, csv

I have json array as follows

```
[{"sno":1,"ref":"123","status":"done"},{"sno":2,"ref":"122","status":"waiting"},
{"sno":3,"ref":"121","status":"pending"}]
```

Now when I click on button, I want to download excel(.csv format) file of above json where  it will contain only two columns "ref" and "status".Does anyone on worked on such thing can please help me here.Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON to CSV format and store in a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable)

Comment: That is not working as expected and is different from what I require

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export JavaScript array info to csv (on client side)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side)