# Convert a JSON into CSV using jq

Tags: json, shell, csv, jq

I have a json file, which is stored in an environment variable temp.

`{
  "users": [
    {
      "username": "jack",
      "email": "jack@somewhere.com",
      "total running apps": "1",
      "api-mock-app": "0",
      "flogo": "1",
      "ipaas": "0",
      "nodejs-app": "0"
    },
    {
      "username": "jill",
      "email": "jill@somewhere.com",
      "total running apps": "1",
      "api-mock-app": "0",
      "flogo": "1",
      "ipaas": "0",
      "nodejs-app": "0"
    }
  ]
}`

When i am converting this JSON into CSV using this command

```
jq -r '.users[] | [.username, .email, .total running apps, .api-mock-app, .flogo, .ipaas, .nodejs-app] | @csv' <<< $temp
```

I am getting following error.

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
.users[] | [.username, .email, .total running apps, .api-mock-app, .flogo, .ipaas, .nodejs-app] | @csv
jq: 1 compile error

Any help Please?

Comment: now the new error is
jq: error: mock/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1: .users[] | [.username, .email, ."total running apps", .api-mock-app, .flogo, .ipaas, .nodejs-app] | @csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote your column names, especially since they contain spaces and dashes. However you need to escape the quotes for bash:

```
jq --raw-output '.users[] | [.username, .email, ."total running apps", ."api-mock-app", ."flogo", ."ipaas", ."nodejs-app"] | @csv'
```

Comment: It's printing keys only, and that too with ., Output is: 
".username",".email",".total running apps",".api-mock-app",".flogo",".ipaas",".nodejs-app"
".username",".email",".total running apps",".api-mock-app",".flogo",".ipaas",".nodejs-app"

Comment: Sorry,  I had the dots at the wrong place (inside the quotes instead of outside. I edited the answer, now it should work

Comment: It worked, can you please  also add keys into CSV first row?

Comment: Can see the data in command line. Any other steps to save as CSV instead of display?

Answer (score 0):

i got this working code [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable#)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo - Covnert JSON to CSV</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // JSON to CSV Converter
        function ConvertToCSV(objArray) {
            var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
            var str = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var line = '';
                for (var index in array[i]) {
                    if (line != '') line += ','

                    line += array[i][index];
                }

                str += line + '\r\n';
            }

            return str;
        }

        // Example
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Create Object
            var items = [
                  { name: "Item 1", color: "Green", size: "X-Large" },
                  { name: "Item 2", color: "Green", size: "X-Large" },
                  { name: "Item 3", color: "Green", size: "X-Large" }];

            // Convert Object to JSON
            var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items);

            // Display JSON
            $('#json').text(jsonObject);

            // Convert JSON to CSV & Display CSV
            $('#csv').text(ConvertToCSV(jsonObject));
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        JSON</h1>
    <pre id="json"></pre>
    <h1>
        CSV</h1>
    <pre id="csv"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

[check out this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable#)