# Custom define Delimiter for -jq while exporting parsed JSON to a CSV file

Tags: json, jq, jupyter-lab, csv

I have a simple query for most of the times it is simple to export the parsed JSON file to various formats including the CSV format. See for reference [Convert a JSON into CSV using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47715234/convert-a-json-into-csv-using-jq)

I want to define `;` as a delimiter for export to `csv` file in the following command in the jupyter-lab magic cell

```
for file in filelist:
    ! echo $file
    ! jq -r '[.user.screen_name, .user.followers_count, .retweeted_status.user.screen_name,\
    .full_text, .display_text_range[1], .created_at, .id, .in_reply_to_user_id, \
    .in_reply_to_status_id, .user.location, .place.name,\
    .user.verified, .retweet_count, .favorite_count, .entities.media[].type, 
    .entities.hashtags[].text] | @csv' < $file >> $store_file
```

tks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to get away with using `join(";")`, but it would almost certainly be better to use `gsub(";";"\\;")` on strings first, but it depends on how you want to handle semicolons in JSON strings. Depending on your requirements or expectations, you might also want to consider using `@tsv` and then postprocessing the tabs, e.g. using

```
sed $'s/\t/;/g'
```

or

```
tr '\t' ';'
```

Comment: where I should be putting the `join(";")` in my command. Help please tks.

Comment: Use `join` instead of `@csv`.