# Best way to store a JSON response into a csv file from Googles location api and the open weather climate api

Tags: javascript, json

Is there any way to store it using javascript?
I'm creating a website which on clicking a button generates and updates a csv file with the json response data from the above

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Perhaps even searching on Google? I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable#8924856

Comment: yes i have
i've tried the code youve mentioned too but since it's  a nested json repsonse , it doesnt work very well. Therfore i asked this question to know the best way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON allows nested structures, whereas CSV is flat. Therefore, you **can't** save JSON as CSV unless:

- you can guarantee that your JSON will never have nested elements
- you can pre-define how nested elements should be flattened
- you wish to store chunks of JSON as single columns in the CSV file (serialization)