# How to Export JSON Response Data in Angular 7

Tags: angular, export-to-csv, angular7

I have JSON Response coming from API. I want to export it to excel sheet in CSV format.

JSON Response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 13,
    "context": "http://tempurl.org",
    "details": [
      {
        "name": "test1"
      },
      {
        "name": "test2"
      }
    ],
    "username": "testuser1",
    "custName": "cap1"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "context": "http://tempurl.org",
    "details": [],
    "username": "testuser2",
    "custName": "cap2"
  }
]
```

Here is a data of CSV that we need to get once it opens on export button click:

```
id      context               username        custName      name
13      http://tempurl.org    testuser1       cap1          test1
13      http://tempurl.org    testuser1       cap1          test2
14      http://tempurl.org    testuser2       cap2
```

Previously I was using gridApi that was doing the csv download but it only works for a visible table whose data we want to export. But not for JSON as in my case.

There is no proper tutorial for the latest angular 7 that cab provide me the insight on how to do this.

Comment: You can have a look to this [library](https://github.com/kauegimenes/jsonexport)

Comment: You can also check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487689/angular-5-how-to-export-data-to-csv-file

Answer (score 3):

You have to create JSON as you want it in excel. and then install `xlsx` and `file-saver` in your app.

```
npm install xlsx

npm install file-saver
```

After this use below service this service have two methods one for export JSON to excel and second for table to excel.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';
@Injectable()
export class ExcelService {
  constructor() { }
  public exportJsonAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
  }
  public exportTableAsExcelFile(table: HTMLElement, excelFileName: string): void {
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(table);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
  }
  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: EXCEL_TYPE });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + new Date().getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use combine your data to csv content and download it use `URL.createObjectURL`

```
download() {
    let fileName = 'download.csv';
    let columnNames = ["id", "context", "username", "custName"];
    let header = columnNames.join(',');

    let csv = header;
    csv += '\r\n';

    this.data.map(c => {
      csv += [c["id"], c["context"], c["username"], c["custName"]].join(',');
      csv += '\r\n';
    })

    var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8;" });

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    if (link.download !== undefined) {
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.setAttribute("href", url);
      link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
  }
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-download-csv2

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to install any external libraries or dependencies. All these could be done with Vanilla JavaScript/TypeScript on your component.ts.

The first line in your CSV file will always be the header.

The subsequent lines will represent each line of data on the CSV line. Therefore, `formattedData` represents the processing of `yourData` to its individual lines, and each 'line' is represented by an array.

After which, you use `Array.join()` to convert the array to the respective string value, separated by a comma.

```
this.yourData = [{"id":13,"context":"http:\/\/tempurl.org","details":[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"}],"username":"testuser1","custName":"cap1"},{"id":14,"context":"http:\/\/tempurl.org","details":[],"username":"testuser2","custName":"cap2"}];

exportData() {
  let currentRow = [];
  const csvHeader = ['id', 'context', 'username', 'custName', 'name'];

  const formattedData = this.yourData.map(row => {
    // do the rest here
    return currentRow;
  });
  let csvContent = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,';

  formattedData.unshift(csvHeader);
  formattedData.forEach(rowArray => {
    const row = rowArray.join(',');
    csvContent += row + '\r\n';
  });

  const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
  window.open(encodedUri);

}
```