# New TypeScript version does not include 'window.navigator.msSaveBlob'

Tags: typescript, dependencies

I have a TypeScript project (https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport) and it is working fine.

After adding the dependabot process, it suggests upgrading typescript:

```
Bump typescript from 4.3.4 to 4.4.3
```

However, because the library that I am maintaining has references to Internet Explorer to old Internet Explorer properties, it fails building with the new version.

Here is a sample of the build errors:

```
src/excellentexport.ts:143:30 - error TS2339: Property 'msSaveBlob' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
143         if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~
src/excellentexport.ts:145:30 - error TS2339: Property 'msSaveBlob' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
145             window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~
src/excellentexport.ts:278:34 - error TS2339: Property 'msSaveBlob' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
```

Should I remove the support for old Internet Explorer? Is the a way to continue using those IE specific properties?

Comment: I would remove support for old IE. They are security nightmares that people need more reasons to let go of. Failing that, it's not TypeScript per se, it's the lib.d.ts and associated files that're bundled with TypeScript that are causing the problem. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/issues/1029

Comment: Whether you should remove IE support depends on whether you/your company want to or have to support it. (Ideally everyone would remove it.)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I ran into the exact same issue recently, and the solution I arrived at was to extend the `Navigator` interface in the `global` namespace so it still includes `msSaveBlob`, based on how `msSaveBlob` is documented by TypeScript here: [MSFileSaver](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.msfilesaver.html#mssaveblob)

Here is the code I used:

```
declare global {
    interface Navigator {
        msSaveBlob?: (blob: any, defaultName?: string) => boolean
    }
}

if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    // use navigator.msSaveBlob
}
```

Comment: Where do I declare that and how to import it?

Comment: Hopefully you'll be able to put it in the same file as you use `msSaveBlob`, that's what I was able to do. TypeScript is a little opinionated about where things like this can go. As I understand it, you have to use this in a file that either imports or exports something. If you don't, you'll get the compilation error "error TS2669: Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations."

Comment: Worked for me thanks. I just put it straight after the imports in the component.

Answer (score 3):

I declared global namespace in my **appmodule.ts** file since its used in multiple files like this

```
 declare global{
 interface Navigator{
    msSaveBlob:(blob: Blob,fileName:string) => boolean
    }
 }
```

And calling file looks like this**//It was throwing build errors like you mentioned,

```
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
   // IE 10+
   navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  if ((window.navigator as any).msSaveBlob) {
        (window.navigator as any).msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
      }
```

Comment: This is the simplest, and achieves the same result => fooling the compiler.