# Generate CSV file using name cell from JSON data in angular

Tags: angular, excel, export-to-excel

The ask is to generate the csv file from JSON data in the format

```
jsonObj = {'key1' : 'value1',
           'key2' : 'value2',...}
```

I need to generate the CSV file using name cell format with 2 columns only

```
key1    value1
key2    value2
.       .
.       .
.       .
```

Including the concept of name cell where clicking on the cell 'value1' the cell is referred to as 'key1' instead of B1.
I am using exportToCSV library in angular but could not find any.
Code for Reference

```
` let csvData = [data.data];
    const options = {
      filename: "Q_String_" + primaryKey,
      fieldSeparator: ",",
      quoteStrings: '"',
      decimalSeparator: ".",
      showLabels: true,
      useTextFile: false,
      useBom: true,
      useKeysAsHeaders: true,
    };

    const csvExporter = new ExportToCsv(options);
    csvExporter.generateCsv(csvData);
    this.toastr.success("Q String has been downloaded","Success"); `
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Can you post the code you tried and explain why it didn't work?

Comment: Ok @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: and why didn't it work?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid. its generating two rows with key (first row) and value (second row) without naming cell references.
I need it to get in two columns having a ability of naming a cell with their keys.
For Ref, [link](https://www.techadvisory.org/2014/03/naming-cells-in-microsoft-office-excel/#:~:text=Each%20cell%20in%20the%20spreadsheet,next%20to%20the%20formula%20bar.)

Comment: Can you edit the question and add a sample of what it is producing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ANGULAR 5 : how to export data to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487689/angular-5-how-to-export-data-to-csv-file)

Comment: @TheFabio, No actually, i am in need to two columns with naming cells

Comment: I does allow you to get two cells (or any other subset...) look at this answer with care and I am sure you will figure it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51488124/4604645