# Best way to convert JSON to CSV while maintaining row structure using JS

Tags: javascript, json, export-to-csv

I have JSON data in the following form:

```
{
  field: ...,
  field: ...,
  field: ...,
  field: ...,
  items: [{array of multiple objects}]
},
{
  field: ...,
  field: ...,
  field: ...,
  field: ...,
  items: [{array of multiple objects}]
},
{
  field: ...,
  field: ...,
  field: ...,
  field: ...,
  items: [{array of multiple objects}]
}
...
```

and so on.
I want to convert it into CSV for report generation, but I'd like each item in that array to have its own row like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsFdR.jpg).

Since I'm building the webapp using VueJS and Firebase, is there any way I can convert and have a downloadable CSV file, through Javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON to CSV format and store in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable)

Comment: See the link of @HyyanAboFakher to create your csv content in a string, then you can have a look at the following link on how to create a downloadable file (pure JS): https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server

Comment: Hey, I'm able to get everyhing in one row, but I'd like to take it further and have each item in items in its own row, like in the image. How can I do that? Would I have to create a new row and set the earlier fields to " "?

Comment: @freeribosome Can you provide the code you already did so we can help you from where you are?

Comment: Here's what I have so far: [Link](https://gist.github.com/kunmishra2599/48e2196fee0396e5df91cd6a7f24d98b)

Comment: So you want 1 object by row, 1 field by column, and for the array of multiple object they are placed in a same column?

Comment: It wouldn't really be one object by row, since multiple items moves it down to multiple rows, but yes that's the general idea.