# Could I parse to `json/[object] using xlsx-populate

Tags: node.js, xlsx-populate

I want to parse an array of objects into xlsx-populate so it can give me the excel file.

```
const xlsxPopulate = require('xlsx-populate');
const worksheet = await xlsxPopulate.fromBlankAsync();
const sheet1 = worksheet.sheet('Sheet1');
sheet1.cell('A1').value(newArray);
await worksheet.toFileAsync('./myFileName.xlsx');
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for Arrays or Arrays(`[[..][..]]`) using `range` or using single cell as well.

From the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-populate#ranges):

> xlsx-populate also supports ranges of cells to allow
>   parsing/manipulation of multiple cells at once.
>
> ```
> const r = workbook.sheet(0).range("A1:C3");
>
> // Set all cell values to the same value:
> r.value(5);
>
> // Set the values using a 2D array:
> r.value([
>     [1, 2, 3],
>     [4, 5, 6],
>     [7, 8, 9]
> ]);
>
> // Set the values using a callback function:
> r.value((cell, ri, ci, range) => Math.random());
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can set the values in a range with only the
>   top-left cell in the range:
>
> ```
> workbook.sheet(0).cell("A1").value([
>     [1, 2, 3],
>     [4, 5, 6],
>     [7, 8, 9]
> ]);
> ```

So all you need to do is converting objects to CSV maybe for an example JS object:

Modified(only removed the `.join`s) From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable):

```
const json = [
    {
        h1:1,
        h2:2
    },
    {
        h1:3,
        h2:4
    }
];
var fields = Object.keys(json[0])
var replacer = function(key, value) { return value === null ? '' : value } 
var csv = json.map(function(row){
  return fields.map(function(fieldName){
    return JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)
  })
})
csv.unshift(fields) // add header column

console.log(csv) //[ [ 'h1', 'h2' ], [ '1', '2' ], [ '3', '4' ] ]
```