# Convert JSON to CSV using js

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

i try to convert flatten json data to csv with js.

js code

```js
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";

let data = [{}, {}] //data export from firebase as an array filled with objects

let dataJson = JSON.stringify(data);

let fileToSave = new Blob([dataJson ], {
  type: "csv",
  name: 'data.csv'
});

saveAs(fileToSave, 'data.csv');
```

my example json

```
[
{"kaab":{"ka11":6,"ka12":6,"ka10":6},"ae":{"a6":2,"a5":2,"a4":6},"kg3":"fdsf","kg2":4,"solz":"2","kg1":5,"ges":1,"kaak":{"ka4":5,"ka1":4,"ka5":3,"ka6":5,"ka3":5,"ka2":4},"eink":"","kawe":{"ka9":4,"ka7":5,"ka8":5},"soz2":"","alt":3,"zul":{"infl":1,"spi":1,"int":1,"les":1,"mer":1,"aut":1,"inf2":1},"kg4":2,"am":{"a1":5,"a3":2,"a2":2}}
{"kaab":{"ka11":6,"ka12":6,"ka10":6},"ae":{"a6":2,"a5":2,"a4":6},"kg3":"fdsf","kg2":4,"solz":"2","kg1":5,"ges":1,"kaak":{"ka4":5,"ka1":4,"ka5":3,"ka6":5,"ka3":5,"ka2":4},"eink":"","kawe":{"ka9":4,"ka7":5,"ka8":5},"soz2":"","alt":3,"zul":{"infl":1,"spi":1,"int":1,"les":1,"mer":1,"aut":1,"inf2":1},"kg4":2,"am":{"a1":5,"a3":2,"a2":2}}
]
```

I have used `file-saver` for this but with no big succes.
I get a csv file for excel, but something is still wrong

[excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ucxp.png)

But I need this as an example
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9VMA.png)

If any of you can help me I really appreciate it. It doesnt need to be done with `file-saver`

Comment: Have you looked at all the other JSON to CSV npm packages?

Comment: Yes I did, several hours. But without success

Comment: You can use this method : [How to convert JSON to CSV format and store in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57788568/8557632)

Comment: I will take a look on it, thank you for the first