# Export data into a CSV in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, formatter, export-csv

I have data in the following format,

```
const data = {
    "Class-1": [{
        "section": "A",
        "total": "45",
        "boys": "31",
        "girls": "14",
        "subjects": 3,
        "class-teacher": "ABC"
    }, {
        "section": "B",
        "total": "30",
        "boys": "20",
        "girls": "10",
        "subjects": 3,
        "class-teacher": "XYZ"
    }],
    "Class-2": [{
        "section": "A",
        "total": "40",
        "boys": "25",
        "girls": "15",
        "subjects": 4,
        "class-teacher": "ABC2"
    }],
    "Class-3": [{
        "section": "A",
        "total": "44",
        "boys": "29",
        "girls": "15",
        "subjects": 4,
        "class-teacher": "ABC3"
    }, {
        "section": "B",
        "total": "40",
        "boys": "29",
        "girls": "11",
        "subjects": 4,
        "class-teacher": "XYZ1"
    }],
    "Class-4": [{
        "section": "A",
        "total": "50",
        "boys": "30",
        "girls": "20",
        "subjects": 5,
        "class-teacher": "ABC4"
    }]
}
```

I want to export the above data in a CSV file with JavaScript, something like as shown below,
[image: Expected]

I tried using `d3-dsv` ([this](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#:%7E:text=This%20module%20provides%20a%20parser,is%20based%20on%20RFC%204180.)), but not able to achieve the desired result. With `d3-dsv`, if I am flattening the data into an immediate array of objects, I am not getting the classes- Class-1, Class-2, Class-3, and Class-4.

With `d3-dsv`, if I give data in the following format, I get output as attached below,
**Data format-**

```
[{
    "section": "A",
    "total": "45",
    "boys": "31",
    "girls": "14",
    "subjects": 3,
    "class-teacher": "ABC"
}, {
    "section": "B",
    "total": "30",
    "boys": "20",
    "girls": "10",
    "subjects": 3,
    "class-teacher": "XYZ"
}, {
    "section": "A",
    "total": "40",
    "boys": "25",
    "girls": "15",
    "subjects": 4,
    "class-teacher": "ABC2"
}, {
    "section": "A",
    "total": "44",
    "boys": "29",
    "girls": "15",
    "subjects": 4,
    "class-teacher": "ABC3"
}, {
    "section": "B",
    "total": "40",
    "boys": "29",
    "girls": "11",
    "subjects": 4,
    "class-teacher": "XYZ1"
}, {
    "section": "A",
    "total": "50",
    "boys": "30",
    "girls": "20",
    "subjects": 5,
    "class-teacher": "ABC4"
}]
```

Output in CSV-
[image: Output]

Comment: It would be simpler from a conversion point of view, to have the headers (section, total etc) on row 1 and the other content beneath ... do you need Class-1 on row 1 and headers on row 2?

Comment: Where is the code you tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I won't mind adding a separate column for class if not row. Like class,section,total,boys,girls,subjects,class-teacher.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I edited my question, pls have a look

Comment: @Vivekkumar - I added a way to do it with d3 methods

Answer (score 3):

Iterate `Object.entries()` and each iteration create the sub heading row and iterate it's array to push the data rows

```js
const headings = ['section', 'total','boys', 'girls', 'subjects', 'class-teacher'];

const rows = [headings];

Object.entries(data).forEach(([k, arr])=>{
    const subHeadRow = Array.from(headings, (el,i) => i ? '' : k); 
    rows.push(subHeadRow)
    arr.forEach(o => rows.push(Object.values(o)));
});

const csv = rows.map(row => row.map(JSON.stringify)).join('\r\n')

console.log(csv)
```

```html
<script>
const data={"Class-1":[{section:"A",total:"45",boys:"31",girls:"14",subjects:3,"class-teacher":"ABC"},{section:"B",total:"30",boys:"20",girls:"10",subjects:3,"class-teacher":"XYZ"}],"Class-2":[{section:"A",total:"40",boys:"25",girls:"15",subjects:4,"class-teacher":"ABC2"}],"Class-3":[{section:"A",total:"44",boys:"29",girls:"15",subjects:4,"class-teacher":"ABC3"},{section:"B",total:"40",boys:"29",girls:"11",subjects:4,"class-teacher":"XYZ1"}],"Class-4":[{section:"A",total:"50",boys:"30",girls:"20",subjects:5,"class-teacher":"ABC4"}]};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Per @charlieftl, you don't need D3 to do this. But if you want to use the d3-dsv library then look at [`d3.csvFormatBody`](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#csvFormatBody) which will take an array of objects and just provide csv formatted row data i.e. no headers.

In the example below, for the 1st row, the headers come from the 1st array item of the 1st key.

Then iterate the keys of the data and for each key output it (e.g. `Class-1`) on a row, then the rows underneath are from the array property.

```js
// linefeed
const lf = `\r\n`;
// keys of object are Class-1, Class-2 etc
const keys = Object.keys(data);
// get headers from 1st array item of 1st key
const headers = Object.keys(data[keys[0]][0]);
// initialise the csv output with the headers
let csv = `${headers}${lf}`;
// for each key, add the Class-N then the rows (with no headers)
keys.forEach(key => csv += `${key}${lf}${d3.csvFormatBody(data[key])}${lf}`);
// output
console.log(csv);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
const data={"Class-1":[{section:"A",total:"45",boys:"31",girls:"14",subjects:3,"class-teacher":"ABC"},{section:"B",total:"30",boys:"20",girls:"10",subjects:3,"class-teacher":"XYZ"}],"Class-2":[{section:"A",total:"40",boys:"25",girls:"15",subjects:4,"class-teacher":"ABC2"}],"Class-3":[{section:"A",total:"44",boys:"29",girls:"15",subjects:4,"class-teacher":"ABC3"},{section:"B",total:"40",boys:"29",girls:"11",subjects:4,"class-teacher":"XYZ1"}],"Class-4":[{section:"A",total:"50",boys:"30",girls:"20",subjects:5,"class-teacher":"ABC4"}]};
</script>
```