# Suprisingly can't find a solution to this. react-csv automatically download to server instead of user choice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I'm generating an invoice, and am using the react-csv package to covert my graphql data into a csv file. problem is I don't want the user to select a location locally to download to (out of the box behavior). It needs to be saved automatically in a hardcoded directory in the server. Anyone???

```
<CSVLink onClick={generateInvoice} className="mt-1 inline-block align-middle  w-full inline-flex justify-center py-2 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-blue-400 hover:bg-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500" filename={csvfilename} data={csvinvoiceForDownload} headers={headers}>
Create Invoice
</CSVLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need react-csv, it is for rendering data...
You can use eg PapaParse
https://www.papaparse.com/docs#json-to-csv
to convert your graphQL object into csv, which you can send with fetch or axios to your server...

```
// With implicit header row
// (keys of first object populate header row)
var csv = Papa.unparse([
    {
        "Column 1": "foo",
        "Column 2": "bar"
    },
    {
        "Column 1": "abc",
        "Column 2": "def"
    }
]);
```

Also you can just use js:

```
const items = json3.items
const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : value // specify how you want to handle null values here
const header = Object.keys(items[0])
const csv = [
  header.join(','), // header row first
  ...items.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','))
].join('\r\n')

console.log(csv)
```

(example found on SO: [How to convert JSON to CSV format and store in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable))

you can find there more options...