# Change JSON Content using any programming language or script or by tools to get data in excel format?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, excel

I have a `.JSON` file (maybe wrong `JSON` structure file, but the extension is `.JSON`) When I use `JSON beautifier` we see as below:

```
 object {2}
    https://example.com/product/Detail/1        [3]
    https://example.com/product/Detail/2        [3]
```

Each of above lines has `Three (3) details (Property)`:

```
https://example.com/product/Detail/1        [3]

    0   :   ACETATE                                
    1   :   SUSPENSION PARENTERAL 40 mg/1mL                                 
    2   :   INJECTION
```

without any consideration that this is a correct JSON file or not, I need an `.xlsx` file and so try to convert it using `JSON` to `CSV` or `EXCEL` Online tools and see following:

[image]

as we can see there is `wrong conversion`, we should have:

[image]

I means we should have `two (2) rows` and for each row we should have `three (3) columns` (property).

What is the easiest way to convert this .JSON file to Excel to get the
above (Second picture)? is there any piece of code, scripts, or tools to can handle it easily?

Update:

This is the JSON file for two records.

```
{
  "https://example.com/product/Detail/1": [
    "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE",
    "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE INJECTION, SUSPENSION PARENTERAL 40 mg/1mL",
    "INJECTION, SUSPENSION",
    "PARENTERAL",
    "البرز دارو",
    "البرز دارو",
    "ریال",
    "ریال",
    "1 AMPULE in 1 CARTON",
    "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE 40 mg/1mL",
    "1397/12/24",
    "60000",
    "60000",
    "06260152433031",
    "3230858996456396",
    "",
    "H02AB04"
  ],
  "https://example.com/product/Detail/2": [
    "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE",
    "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE INJECTION, SUSPENSION PARENTERAL 40 mg/1mL",
    "INJECTION, SUSPENSION",
    "PARENTERAL",
    "کارخانجات دارو پخش",
    "کارخانجات دارو پخش",
    "ریال",
    "ریال",
    "1 AMPULE in 1 BOX",
    "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE 40 mg/1mL",
    "1400/09/22",
    "60000",
    "60000",
    "06260132425704",
    "2903849236347759",
    "",
    "H02AB04"
  ]
}
```

Comment: nothing wrong with the conversion, it converts to column instead to row.

Comment: You've listed three entirely different languages and one framework, please pick one. Please do not post pictures of code or data, please paste as text only. Please also show your current attempt, or explain why you couldn't find the answer on Google, as all these languages have well documented JSON libraries?

Comment: @MangHartono How I can change this? this is my goal.

Comment: @Charlieface I completely disagree with you, anyway thanks

Comment: Which bit do you not agree with, I'd love to know which bit is problematic. This one https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354931/when-is-it-appropriate-to-tag-multiple-languages-in-my-question or this one https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question or this one https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/?

Comment: @user355834, assuming that your final sheet is in Excel, the simplest way to solve it is to [transpose (rotate)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-rotate-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa-3419f2e3-beab-4318-aae5-d0f862209744) your sheet.

Comment: @MangHartono it's very difficult for 5000 rows... it's better to read JSON and then convert it or any other solution except you promote here. thanks so much for your help

Comment: I can build you a python script, can you add detail to your question, by giving a small portion of your JSON?

Comment: @MangHartono very nice. I attach and upload JSON file for two records. I need  to convert to the second picture. I put a bounty on this question also.

Comment: Hi... please put the json as text inside the question itself.

Comment: @TheMaster Sure.

Comment: It makes it easy to copy and test in any code... Are you open to using Google sheets?

Comment: @TheMaster when I have 5000 records, it's not easily done in Google Sheet.

Comment: 5k records shouldn't be a issue. Try [`ImportJSONFromSheet`](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON) for Google sheets. If you want excel only, try   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba

Comment: @TheMaster when convert this json to CSV or XLSX we have so many rows, we should change it to get attribute for each link in one row and many columns. I try both features and not succeed.

Comment: @TheMaster is it possible to say how import using importjson in google sheet using json file on Google Drive?

Comment: If the file is shared publicly in. Google drive, you can use the URL in importjson.

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster for your all helps, not works in google drive. this is my main problem. would you please post it as an answer and show me?

Comment: I'm not getting you. What is not working in Google drive?

Comment: @user355834, check the solution that I provided and let me know if I can be of any further assistance.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a json to a excel sheet, there are wide variety of tools. I'll list some common ways to do this:

[python](/questions/tagged/python)

Here we can use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/). The idea is to create a `array` of rows and `.append` each `row`

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
import json

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
dic = json.loads('''
{
  "https://example.com/product/Detail/1": [
    "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE",
    "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE INJECTION, SUSPENSION PARENTERAL 40 mg/1mL",
    "INJECTION, SUSPENSION",
    "PARENTERAL",
    "البرز دارو",
    "البرز دارو",
    "ریال",
    "ریال",
    "1 AMPULE in 1 CARTON",
    "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE 40 mg/1mL",
    "1397/12/24",
    "60000",
    "60000",
    "06260152433031",
    "3230858996456396",
    "",
    "H02AB04"
  ],
  "https://example.com/product/Detail/2": [
    "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE",
    "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE INJECTION, SUSPENSION PARENTERAL 40 mg/1mL",
    "INJECTION, SUSPENSION",
    "PARENTERAL",
    "کارخانجات دارو پخش",
    "کارخانجات دارو پخش",
    "ریال",
    "ریال",
    "1 AMPULE in 1 BOX",
    "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE 40 mg/1mL",
    "1400/09/22",
    "60000",
    "60000",
    "06260132425704",
    "2903849236347759",
    "",
    "H02AB04"
  ]
}
        ''')

for product in dic:
    ws.append([product]+dic[product])
# print([(lambda a: [b.value for b in a])(a) for a in ws['A1':'Z2']])
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

[node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js)

Use [sheetsjs](https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/example). Convert the `json` to a `aoa`( array of arrays) using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and write to the file:

```js
const XLSX = require('xlsx'),
  wb = XLSX.utils.book_new(),
  json = /*If necessary use JSON.parse()*/ {
    'https://example.com/product/Detail/1': [
      'METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE',
      'METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE INJECTION, SUSPENSION PARENTERAL 40 mg/1mL',
      'INJECTION, SUSPENSION',
      'PARENTERAL',
      'البرز دارو',
      'البرز دارو',
      'ریال',
      'ریال',
      '1 AMPULE in 1 CARTON',
      'METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE 40 mg/1mL',
      '1397/12/24',
      '60000',
      '60000',
      '06260152433031',
      '3230858996456396',
      '',
      'H02AB04',
    ],
    'https://example.com/product/Detail/2': [
      'METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE',
      'METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE INJECTION, SUSPENSION PARENTERAL 40 mg/1mL',
      'INJECTION, SUSPENSION',
      'PARENTERAL',
      'کارخانجات دارو پخش',
      'کارخانجات دارو پخش',
      'ریال',
      'ریال',
      '1 AMPULE in 1 BOX',
      'METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE 40 mg/1mL',
      '1400/09/22',
      '60000',
      '60000',
      '06260132425704',
      '2903849236347759',
      '',
      'H02AB04',
    ],
  },
  data = Object.entries(json).map(([k, v]) => [k, v].flat()),
  ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(data);
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws);
XLSX.writeFileXLSX(wb, 'test.xlsx');
```

Live snippet creating downloadable xlsx from given data:

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
  const json = /*If necessary use JSON.parse()*/ {
      'https://example.com/product/Detail/1': [
        'METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE',
        'METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE INJECTION, SUSPENSION PARENTERAL 40 mg/1mL',
        'INJECTION, SUSPENSION',
        'PARENTERAL',
        'البرز دارو',
        'البرز دارو',
        'ریال',
        'ریال',
        '1 AMPULE in 1 CARTON',
        'METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE 40 mg/1mL',
        '1397/12/24',
        '60000',
        '60000',
        '06260152433031',
        '3230858996456396',
        '',
        'H02AB04',
      ],
      'https://example.com/product/Detail/2': [
        'METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE',
        'METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE INJECTION, SUSPENSION PARENTERAL 40 mg/1mL',
        'INJECTION, SUSPENSION',
        'PARENTERAL',
        'کارخانجات دارو پخش',
        'کارخانجات دارو پخش',
        'ریال',
        'ریال',
        '1 AMPULE in 1 BOX',
        'METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE 40 mg/1mL',
        '1400/09/22',
        '60000',
        '60000',
        '06260132425704',
        '2903849236347759',
        '',
        'H02AB04',
      ],
    },
    rows = Object.entries(json).map(([k, v]) => [k, v].flat()),
    wb = XLSX.utils.book_new(),
    ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(rows);
  console.table(rows)
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws);
  XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'json.xlsx');
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

[google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets)[google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)

Use [importjson](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON) or use `array.map` technique shown above  to create a array of arrays and `setValues()` the `aoa`.

Comment: The snippet doesn't produce any output, does it?

Comment: @David It will create a direct download on your device. Edit: It should create output now on the console.

Comment: Yes right, now it shows the data in a table

Comment: @David Did you not get a download notification?

Comment: No, here with the snippet it doesn't seem to work. I use chrome as browser

Comment: Opera and FireFox neither offer a Download

Comment: @David Thanks for testing. Probably due to zero click restrictions... I only tested in Firefox mobile(most restricted browser) at the time and it worked....so I thought it'll work in everywhere else. You're right. Tested in chrome and it didn't offer a download...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple class in PHP that should do just what you want. It can be modified easily if you need to. It reads the JSON file and creates a CSV file in an uploads folder.

```php
<?php

namespace App;

class CSVFromJson
{
    private $separator = ",";
    private $filename = 'export';
    private $json_file;

    public function __construct(string $file_path, string $filename = null, string $separator = null)
    {
        $this->json_file = $file_path;
        $this->filename = $filename ?? $this->filename;
        $this->separator = $separator ?? $this->separator;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->process_file();
    }

    private function process_file()
    {
        $json_content = file_get_contents($this->json_file);
        $json_content = json_decode($json_content);
        $csv_content = "";

        foreach ($json_content as $key => $value) {
            $csv_content .= $key . $this->separator;
            
            foreach ($value as $data) $csv_content .= $data . $this->separator;
            $csv_content = substr($csv_content, 0, -1);
            $csv_content .= "\n";
        }

        $csv_content = substr($csv_content, 0, -1);

        if (!file_exists(dirname(__FILE__, 2) . '/uploads')) {
            mkdir(dirname(__FILE__, 2) . '/uploads');
        }

        $file = $this->filename . '_' . time() . '.csv';
        $path = dirname(__FILE__, 2) . '/uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
        $csv_file = fopen($path,"w") or die('Unable to read file');
        fwrite($csv_file, $csv_content);
        fclose($csv_file);

        return $path;
    }
}
```

Here's a sample:

```php
use App\CSVFromJson;

$JSONCSVExporter = new CSVFromJson(__DIR__ . '/test.json');
$JSONCSVExporter->execute();
```

Comment: In PHP you could use [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php). Also --like [my answer with javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72955096/1019850)-- this solution doesn't escape and ignores many details. I think that's fine according to the question, as that was about the general logic, but using the code without further efforts isn't advisable.

Comment: Yes David. This is a really basic solution, and I did say it could be modified as needed. This solves the immediate problem and assumes the data is correctly formatted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How to solve your problem:

- first, save your JSON data as `data.json` file.
- copy the following python script below, and don't forget to import the `pandas` and `openpyxl` packages.
- run the script.

Python script for your need:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

dataJsonFile = 'data.json' #change the file name according to your need
xlsxTempFile = 'temp.xlsx'
xlsxFinal = 'result.xlsx'

#create and load xlsx file from JSON data file
pd.read_json(dataJsonFile).to_excel(xlsxTempFile)
xlsxFile = load_workbook(xlsxTempFile)
sheet = xlsxFile.active

#processing xlsx file
title = [ #change the title according to your need
  'url',
  'x01',
  'x02',
  'x03',
  'x04',
  'x05',
  'x06',
  'x07',
  'x08',
  'x09',
  'x10',
  'x11',
  'x12',
  'x13',
  'x14',
  'x15',
  'x16',
  'x17'
  ]

for i in range(len(title)):
  sheet.cell(i+1, 1).value = title[i] #add title
xlsxFile.save(xlsxTempFile) #save it

df = pd.read_excel(xlsxTempFile, engine='openpyxl')

dfTranspose = df.T #transpose the dataframe
dfTranspose.to_excel(xlsxFinal, header=None) #save it to final xlsx
```

The result xlsx file:
[image]

Script explanation:

- using `pandas` to convert your JSON data to `temp.xlsx` file.
- read the `temp.xlsx` file using `openpyxl` and add the details for title.
- open the resulting `temp.xlsx` using `pandas` again and then *transpose* it.
- write the result to `result.xlsx`.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

In nodeJS you can do

```
let json = {
    "https://example.com/product/Detail/1": [
      "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE",
      "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE INJECTION, SUSPENSION PARENTERAL 40 mg/1mL",
      "INJECTION, SUSPENSION",
      "PARENTERAL",
      "البرز دارو",
      "البرز دارو",
      "ریال",
      "ریال",
      "1 AMPULE in 1 CARTON",
      "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE 40 mg/1mL",
      "1397/12/24",
      "60000",
      "60000",
      "06260152433031",
      "3230858996456396",
      "",
      "H02AB04"
    ],
    "https://example.com/product/Detail/2": [
      "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE",
      "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE INJECTION, SUSPENSION PARENTERAL 40 mg/1mL",
      "INJECTION, SUSPENSION",
      "PARENTERAL",
      "کارخانجات دارو پخش",
      "کارخانجات دارو پخش",
      "ریال",
      "ریال",
      "1 AMPULE in 1 BOX",
      "METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE 40 mg/1mL",
      "1400/09/22",
      "60000",
      "60000",
      "06260132425704",
      "2903849236347759",
      "",
      "H02AB04"
    ]
  }
  
let {writeFileSync} = require('fs')



let csv = ''

let keys = Object.keys(json)

keys.forEach((n)=>{
    csv+=n+',';
    json[n].forEach((m)=>{
        csv+=m+','
    })
    csv+='\n'
})
console.log(csv,"written to out.csv")
writeFileSync('out.csv',csv)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Excel’s built-in “Power Query Editor”, without coding.
Here the steps with a similar, but smaller, JSON file (data.json):

```
{
  "SET 1": [
    "YYY",
    "XXX",
    "ZZZ"
  ],
  "SET 2": [
    "QQQ",
    "WWW",
    "EEE"
  ]
}
```

1. Open the JSON file from “**Data > Get Data > From File**” menu.
   [image]
2. Convert into a table (click the “**Into Table**” button).
   [image]
3. Expand the 2nd column (the button inside the “**value**” column title) with the “Extract values” option.
   [image]
4. Select a custom separator character (not used in the JSON text), and press OK.
   [image]
5. Split the “value” column by delimiter.
   [image]
6. Select the custom delimiter and the split into columns options. Press OK.
   [image]
7. Press the “**Close & Load**” button at the "**Home**" ribbon
   [image]
8. The results:
   [image]

The behind script can be found too (there is a code after all). Open the “Power Query Editor” again for the same source (you can double click it on the “Queries & Connections” side pane) and select it from the “View > Advanced Editor” ribbon menu button. The script language is called: “Power Query M language”. This above example steps will give this script:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("E:\temp\data.json")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Converted to Table", {"Value", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "~"), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("~", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Value.1", "Value.2", "Value.3"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Value.1", type text}, {"Value.2", type text}, {"Value.3", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `pandas` library from Python to easily parse json files into tabular data. Then write the pandas dataframe to an excel file.

First you'd need to install pandas and openpyxl by running the below from the terminal

```
pip install pandas openpyxl
```

Then you can use pandas to read the json file from disk and save it to an excel file

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("data.json", orient="index")
df.to_excel("data.xlsx", header=False)
```

The excel file looks like this:
[screenshot of excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofpmd.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple JavaScript solution, you can adjust linebreaks in the line `csv += "<br><br>\n";`.

For large datasets it is likely possible to append the current line to the result, so that the result is not gathering more than a line, this would keep the required memory small and work on streams too.
Needs some more work though.

If you use it on a website, you've to set `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` in the header, else your Arabic characters are obstructed.

**Warning:** the code is working only on the provided example and doesn't consider many things like escaping or objects as values, numbers are just treated as strings. It doesn't work recursively either, nor it does provide a download link. All these features are possible and it's advised to spend more efforts on the code to implement those. Many problems and features are mentioned on this side: [How to convert JSON to CSV format and store in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable/)

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "https://example.com/product/Detail/1": [
"METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE",
"METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE INJECTION, SUSPENSION PARENTERAL 40 mg/1mL",
"INJECTION, SUSPENSION",
"PARENTERAL",
"البرز دارو",
"البرز دارو",
"ریال",
"ریال",
"1 AMPULE in 1 CARTON",
"METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE 40 mg/1mL",
"1397/12/24",
"60000",
"60000",
"06260152433031",
"3230858996456396",
"",
"H02AB04"
  ],
  "https://example.com/product/Detail/2": [
"METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE",
"METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE INJECTION, SUSPENSION PARENTERAL 40 mg/1mL",
"INJECTION, SUSPENSION",
"PARENTERAL",
"کارخانجات دارو پخش",
"کارخانجات دارو پخش",
"ریال",
"ریال",
"1 AMPULE in 1 BOX",
"METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE 40 mg/1mL",
"1400/09/22",
"60000",
"60000",
"06260132425704",
"2903849236347759",
"",
"H02AB04"
  ]
}

// console.log(jsonObj);

var properties;
var row = [];
var rows = [];
var n = 0;
var csv = '';
for(url in jsonObj) {
properties = jsonObj[url];
row[0] = url;
csv += '"' + url + '"';
for(index in properties) {
    row[index + 1] = properties[index];
    csv += ', "' + properties[index] + '"';
}
rows[n++] = row;
csv += "<br><br>\n";

}
// console.log(csv);
$('#csv').html(csv);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
   


<div id="csv">
</div>
```