# How to convert JSON Object to a CSV file

Tags: json, csv, csvwriter

I am getting JSON object from RedCAP API.

var result = redcap_api.ExportRecordsAsync(apiToken).Result;

How do I create a CSV file of result? I have installed NuGet packages RedCapAPI and CsvHelper.

Comment: 1. Don't use ".Result". It is generally not safe and might cause deadlocks. Use var result = await redcap_api.ExportRecordsAsync(apiToken) instead
2. Read the CsvHelper docs: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the CSV file to be downloaded and saved as a file?  Or do you instead need to save the CSV as a variable for later use?

For the first use case, there are a few tools available like [this one](https://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm).

For the second use case, try taking a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable).

Of course, you can likely do both (save the CSV as a file, and then reference the file itself later in the script), but without knowing much more hopefully the above links will help you.