# Create csv file using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a json object:

```
{
  "name":"ABC",
  "address_line_1": "House no 12",
  "address_line_2": "Near park",
  "phone_number": "12326728772"
}
```

I want to save these details in a csv file.
How can i do it without using any plugins simply in developer tools?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting json object to csv format in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257062/converting-json-object-to-csv-format-in-javascript)

Comment: @meenakshi, Do you download the csv or just read

Comment: csv file should get created/updated whenever i run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using a server side language like php to create the csv file, tried that before.. just googled stuffs up