# Summarize JSON in table

Tags: json, datatable, summary

I have small JSON like this:

```
let testJson = [
  {"date":"2019.05.21","name":"Péter","num":"8"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.22","name":"Norbert","num":"6"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.21","name":"Sándor","num":"7"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.24","name":"Béla","num":"4"},    
  {"date":"2019.05.23","name":"Sándor","num":"5"},  
  {"date":"2019.05.26","name":"Sándor","num":"6"},  
  {"date":"2019.05.27","name":"Péter","num":"7"},  
  {"date":"2019.05.28","name":"Péter","num":"8"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.29","name":"Péter","num":"3"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.30","name":"Péter","num":"6"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.31","name":"Péter","num":"4"}
];
```

I would like to aggregate the data like this:

[image]

Comment: I just want to display the table in an image in an angular application

Comment: You can see the example in the picture. The first column shows the dates and the columns contain the "num" values for the names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let testJson = [
  {"date":"2019.05.21","name":"Péter","num":"8"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.22","name":"Norbert","num":"6"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.21","name":"Sándor","num":"7"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.24","name":"Béla","num":"4"},    
  {"date":"2019.05.23","name":"Sándor","num":"5"},  
  {"date":"2019.05.26","name":"Sándor","num":"6"},  
  {"date":"2019.05.27","name":"Péter","num":"7"},  
  {"date":"2019.05.28","name":"Péter","num":"8"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.29","name":"Péter","num":"3"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.30","name":"Péter","num":"6"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.31","name":"Péter","num":"4"}
];
const groupBy = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, ele)=>( (acc[ele.date] = acc[ele.date] || []).push(ele), acc),{})
const reformat = ([k, v])=> ({date:k,...Object.assign({},...v.map(l=>({[l.name]:l.num})))})
const result = Object.entries(groupBy(testJson))
.map(ele=>reformat(ele));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works well, but how can I display values ​​in a table?

Comment: @Langosfun, show this lien, it s very helpful,  [converting-json-object-to-csv-format-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257062/converting-json-object-to-csv-format-in-javascript)

Comment: There is no simple solution in angular (for example * ngFor) to display this?

Comment: @Langosfun, this is a solution with ngFor [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9slnb)  :)

Comment: Huge thanks for your help. Can names be written dynamically?

Comment: @Langosfun, yes we can :) [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9slnb)

Comment: Hello! Sorry :( I have new problem...can i create this table easy from this json: http://pasted.co/e1e77b95

Comment: @Langosfun i added an other solution in the below post :)

Answer (score 0):

Other solution with this format [example json format](http://pasted.co/e1e77b95):

```js
let testJson = [
  {"date":"2019.05.21","name":"Péter","num":"8"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.22","name":"Norbert","num":"6"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.21","name":"Sándor","num":"7"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.24","name":"Béla","num":"4"},    
  {"date":"2019.05.23","name":"Sándor","num":"5"},  
  {"date":"2019.05.26","name":"Sándor","num":"6"},  
  {"date":"2019.05.27","name":"Péter","num":"7"},  
  {"date":"2019.05.28","name":"Péter","num":"8"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.29","name":"Péter","num":"3"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.30","name":"Péter","num":"6"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.31","name":"Péter","num":"4"}
];
const groupBy = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, ele)=>( (acc[ele.date] = acc[ele.date] || []).push(ele), acc),{})
const reformat = ([k, v])=> ({[k]:v.map((res,i)=>({id:i, name:res.name, datum:res.date, number:res.num}))})
const result = Object.entries(groupBy(testJson))
.map(ele=>reformat(ele));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not the json needs me but the "Angular" table :(

Answer (score 0):

Another option, that's easier to understand:

```
let testJson = [
  {"date":"2019.05.21","name":"Péter","num":"8"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.22","name":"Norbert","num":"6"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.21","name":"Sándor","num":"7"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.24","name":"Béla","num":"4"},    
  {"date":"2019.05.23","name":"Sándor","num":"5"},  
  {"date":"2019.05.26","name":"Sándor","num":"6"},  
  {"date":"2019.05.27","name":"Péter","num":"7"},  
  {"date":"2019.05.28","name":"Péter","num":"8"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.29","name":"Péter","num":"3"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.30","name":"Péter","num":"6"}, 
  {"date":"2019.05.31","name":"Péter","num":"4"}
];


function summarizeJsonData (data) {
  let keyMap = {};
  let res = [];

  function insert (data) {
    let index = keyMap[data["date"]];
    if (!res[index][data['name']]) res[index][data['name']] = 0;
    res[index][data['name']] += data['num'] 
  }
  
  for (let d of data) {
    if (keyMap[d['date']] === undefined) {
      keyMap[d['date']] = res.length;
      res.push({date: d['date']});
    };
    insert(d)
  }

  return res;
}

console.log(summarizeJsonData(testJson))
```