# save CSV from an array of objects in VueJs 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, export-to-csv

I want to save an array of objects to a `CSV` file, I have tried the following code based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68146412), but my code didn't work well, can you please tell me how can I fix it? thanks in advance.

```html
<template>
  <div @click="saveLogs()">save csv</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  methods: {
    /****************************************
     * https://stackoverflow.com/a/68146412
     ****************************************/
    arrayToCsv(data) {
      return data
        .map(
          (row) =>
            row
              .map(String) // convert every value to String
              .map((v) => v.replaceAll('"', '""')) // escape double colons
              .map((v) => `"${v}"`) // quote it
              .join(",") // comma-separated
        )
        .join("\r\n"); // rows starting on new lines
    },
    /**************************************************************
     * downloadBlob(csv, 'export.csv', 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;')
     *************************************************************/
    downloadBlob(content, filename, contentType) {
      // Create a blob
      var blob = new Blob([content], { type: contentType });
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      // Create a link to download it
      var pom = document.createElement("a");
      pom.href = url;
      pom.setAttribute("download", filename);
      pom.click();
    },
    saveLogs() {
      const myLogs = this.arrayToCsv([
        { act_id: 44, actor: "robot_arm", color: "yellow", lego: "yb1", pick: {x: 1, y: 2, z:5} },
        { act_id: 44, actor: "robot_arm", color: "yellow", lego: "yb2", pick: {x: 1, y: 2, z:5} },
      ]);
      this.downloadBlob(myLogs, "./gui_logs.csv", "text/csv;charset=utf-8;");
      console.log("Logs has been saved");
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: you don't have a 2D array, so that won't work, replace `arrayToCsv` with for example this: [Converting JSON object to CSV format in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58769574/4321299)

Comment: Can you elaborate that "what didn't work well"?

Comment: @Duannx the `csv` file was not saved!

Comment: Absolutely! But you need to debug which step is not working or if is there any error

Comment: The above code is working, except I wasn't emitting / receiving the event correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @traynor suggestion here is the full answer:

```js
/* https://stackoverflow.com/a/58769574 */
arrayToCsv(data) {
    const array = [Object.keys(data[0])].concat(data)

    return array.map(it => {
        return Object.values(it).toString()
    }).join('\n');
},

/* https://stackoverflow.com/a/68146412 */
/* downloadBlob(csv, 'export.csv', 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;')*/
downloadBlob(content, filename, contentType) {
    // Create a blob
    var blob = new Blob([content], { type: contentType });
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // Create a link to download it
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.href = url;
    pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
    pom.click();
},

/* store.js
logs: [
        {
            time_stamp: new Date().toISOString(),
            message: " ============{ Logs }============",
            color: "white",
            name: 0,
        }
    ],
*/
saveLogs() { 
    const myLogs = this.arrayToCsv(store.logs);
    this.downloadBlob(myLogs, './gui_logs.csv', 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;');
    console.log("Logs has been saved");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You try to do it like it's a 2D array, but it's an array of JSON objects.
Like @traynor said, read this :

- [Converting JSON object to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257062/converting-json-object-to-csv-format-in-javascript/58769574#58769574)

You can read this too :

- [JSON to CSV - Javascript client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable)

Also consider using npm library like `csv-writer` (install with `npm i csv-writer`). You can find out an example [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-writer).

When downloading the file, I suggest you to set content-type to 'text/csv' and filename without './'. After clicking `a` link you should remove it like that : `pom.remove()`