# How to download a temporary file

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a short PHP script that takes a JSON string, converts it to CSV format (using `fputcsv`), and makes that CSV available as a downloaded .csv file.  My thought was to use `tmpfile()` to not worry about cronjobs or running out of disk space, but I can't seem to make the magic happen.

Here's my attempt, which is a converted example from [the PHP docs of `readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#refsect1-function.readfile-examples):

```
$tmp = tmpfile();
$jsonArray = json_decode( $_POST['json'] );
fputcsv($tmp, $jsonArray);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($tmp));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmp));

ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($tmp);
```

I feel like the `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding` headers are wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix them.  For example, `basename($tmp)` doesn't seem to return anything, and I'm not sure `text/csv` transfers as binary encoding. Likewise, `echo filesize($tmp)` is blank as well.  Is there a way to do what I'm attempting here?

**[Edit]**

**Below is the working code I wrote as a result of the accepted answer:*

```
$jsonArray = json_decode( $_POST['json'], true );
$tmpName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'data');
$file = fopen($tmpName, 'w');

fputcsv($file, $jsonArray);
fclose($file);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmpName));

ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($tmpName);

unlink($tmpName);
```

Comment: For a javascript solution to this problem, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130849/convert-json-format-to-csv-format-for-ms-excel.

Comment: Does `json_decode` return `null` by any chance?

Comment: So the file is just do not want to be downloaded? and opened in browser? that is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that `tmpfile()` returns a file handle, but all the functions you have need a file *path* (i.e a string), not a handle - notably `basename`, `filesize`, and `readfile`. So none of those function calls will work correctly. Also `basename` won't return a file extension either. Just call it whatever you want, i.e

```
'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv'
```

As @Joshua Burns also says, make sure you're passing in an array to `fputcsv` or use the `assoc` parameter.

Comment: This was everything needed to solve the issue.  I'll edit the working code into the question so people can see the fix.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`json_decode()` by default translates elements into objects rather than arrays. `fputcsv()` expects the data passed to be an array.

I'd recommend changing:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode( $_POST['json'] );
```

To:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode( $_POST['json'], True );
```

And see if that doesn't fix your problem.

When attempting to tackle problems such as these I'd highly recommend enabling `display_errors` and setting `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` to see if there some sort of error you are missing out on:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// Rest of your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check this string out, i would change it to:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($tmp).'"');
```

i had the problem with it once, with browser compatibility :)

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that [tmpfile()](http://php.net/tmpfile) returns a file handle, while [filesize](http://php.net/filesize) takes a filename as parameter.
The following line:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmp));
```

probably gets evaluated as:

```
header('Content-Length: 0');
```

Check that all the calls to header() are executed before any output happens.