# How to add filename and file extension to window.open method that exports a JSON array to a CSV string then to a file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, excel, file, csv

I have the following code, which was found on the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4130939/1055971

```
function DownloadJSON2CSV(objArray)
{
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

    var str = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';

        for (var index in array[i]) {
            line += array[i][index] + ',';
        }

        line.slice(0,line.Length-1); 

        str += line + '\r\n';
    }

    window.open( "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(str))

}
```

This code works very well.  It downloads the file and saves it, but the issue is there is not a way to add a custom title to the file, and also, the file saves with no extension.  **For example, when the save function is called, the file name is 'download' by default with no file extension.**  When i add an extension through the windows file system (like .csv) and open the file again, all data is perfectly preserved.
**I am hoping to figure out a way to preset the file name and file type before the download takes place. Any ideas?**

Answer (score 2):

create invisible link element( anchor tag) and initialize ***download*** property of ***a*** element with desired  file name  and append in new created window and open and call programmatically click event on created ***a*** element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var data = $('#txt').val();
        if(data == '')
            return;
        
        JSONToCSVConvertor(data, "Sample Report", true);
    });
});

function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {
    //If JSONData is not an object then JSON.parse will parse the JSON string in an Object
    var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;
    
    var CSV = '';    
    //Set Report title in first row or line
    
    CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';

    //This condition will generate the Label/Header
    if (ShowLabel) {
        var row = "";
        
        //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
        for (var index in arrData[0]) {
            
            //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
            row += index + ',';
        }

        row = row.slice(0, -1);
        
        //append Label row with line break
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }
    
    //1st loop is to extract each row
    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        var row = "";
        
        //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
        for (var index in arrData[i]) {
            row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
        }

        row.slice(0, row.length - 1);
        
        //add a line break after each row
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    if (CSV == '') {        
        alert("Invalid data");
        return;
    }   
    
    //Generate a file name
    var fileName = "MyReport_";
    //this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
    fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g,"_");   
    
    //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
    var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);
    
    // Now the little tricky part.
    // you can use either>> window.open(uri);
    // but this will not work in some browsers
    // or you will not get the correct file extension    
    
    //this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
    var link = document.createElement("a");    
    link.href = uri;
    
    //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
    link.style = "visibility:hidden";
    link.download = fileName + ".csv";
    
    //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

```css
.txtarea{
    max-width:100%;
    min-height:200px;    
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}

.mydiv{
    padding:10px;
}

.gen_btn{
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#743ED9;
    color:white;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    border:2px solid black;
}

.gen_btn:hover{
    background-color:#9a64ff;
}
```

```html
<div class='mydiv'>    
    <textarea id="txt" class='txtarea'>[{"Vehicle":"BMW","Date":"30, Jul 2013 09:24 AM","Location":"Hauz Khas, Enclave, New Delhi, Delhi, India","Speed":42},{"Vehicle":"Honda CBR","Date":"30, Jul 2013 12:00 AM","Location":"Military Road,  West Bengal 734013,  India","Speed":0},{"Vehicle":"Supra","Date":"30, Jul 2013 07:53 AM","Location":"Sec-45, St. Angel's School, Gurgaon, Haryana, India","Speed":58},{"Vehicle":"Land Cruiser","Date":"30, Jul 2013 09:35 AM","Location":"DLF Phase I, Marble Market, Gurgaon, Haryana, India","Speed":83},{"Vehicle":"Suzuki Swift","Date":"30, Jul 2013 12:02 AM","Location":"Behind Central Bank RO, Ram Krishna Rd by-lane, Siliguri, West Bengal, India","Speed":0},{"Vehicle":"Honda Civic","Date":"30, Jul 2013 12:00 AM","Location":"Behind Central Bank RO, Ram Krishna Rd by-lane, Siliguri, West Bengal, India","Speed":0},{"Vehicle":"Honda Accord","Date":"30, Jul 2013 11:05 AM","Location":"DLF Phase IV, Super Mart 1, Gurgaon, Haryana, India","Speed":71}]</textarea>
    <button class='gen_btn'>Generate File</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work here, and when I integrate something similar in my project I get "Failed - Network error" in Chrome on my mac

Answer (score -1):

```
//taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri#15832569
function downloadWithName(uri, name) {
    function eventFire(el, etype){
        if (el.fireEvent) {
            (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
        } else {
            var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
            evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
            el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
        }
    }

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    eventFire(link, "click");
}

downloadWithName("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(str), "file.csv"); //didnt work when I tested in ff25
```

There appears to not be a good way to [guarantee the behaviour cross browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri)

Comment: That didnt seem to work.  The browser didnt throw an error, but the download sequence was the same with the default file name still 'default' with no extension.

Comment: Hmm, ya that was just a guess doesn't work reliably cross browsers apparently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri