# convert JSON to excel file using javascript and to apply filters on each column before exporting the file

Tags: javascript, excel

I was going through the possibilities of converting the json into an excel.
I came across this post in stack overflow which was very helpful
[how to export json data to excel file using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230518/how-to-export-json-data-to-excel-file-using-javascript)
Now, I want to improvise on this, along with the coversion to .csv file i wnat it to have filters to the columns.
Is there any way to do this??

Comment: probably ... what have you tried?

Comment: Not able to proceed, because i am not sure how to start with it