# Download comma separated stríng as csv

Tags: javascript, html, json, csv

I have created below code which takes a JSON object and convert it to comma separated through the ConvertToCSV function. My question is then how i can take the variable csvData and download it as a csv file?

This code is already in a function which is being executed on button click

```
  var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(data);
  var toCSV = ConvertToCSV(jsonObject);
  var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(toCSV);
```

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130849/convert-json-format-to-csv-format-for-ms-excel/4130939#4130939

Answer (score 3):

use blob to store it locally and then download it. e.g

http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/cw7w5/

```
var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(data),
            blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());

var data = { x: 42, s: "hello, world", d: new Date() },
    fileName = "my-download.json";

saveData(data, fileName);
```

this http://jsfiddle.net/e5ggkkur/1/ will work in firefox

Comment: Is it me or this fiddle does nothing, at least on firefox?

Comment: @Takendarkk true, but does not works in firefox or ie

Comment: @Johnny5 try this http://jsfiddle.net/e5ggkkur/1/ will work in firefox and chrome

Comment: @vijayshiyani the type should be `application/octet-stream`, octet/stream does not exist.