# Print Object into a CSV file with Javascript / NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a API with NodeJS

I want to print into a CSV File a Object like this

```
[
 {
  "birthday":"1992-01-01",
  "email":"test@mail.com",
  "gender":"male"
 },
 {
  "birthday":"2000-03-23",
  "email":"test2@mail.com",
 }
]
```

And I want this in my CSV File

```
birthday,email,gender
1992-01-01,test@gmail.com,male
2000-03-23,test2@mail.com
```

For print CSV I using

```
var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + encodeURI(show);
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
hiddenElement.download = 'result.csv';
hiddenElement.click();
```

But in the CSV file prints [Object object]

ANy help? Thanks!

Comment: Did you search? [`[javascript] object to csv`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+object+to+csv)

Comment: Yes I do, but I have found not work totally for me

Comment: Then please explain which solutions you have tried and why they do not work. E.g. why does the function in http://stackoverflow.com/q/4130849/218196 not work for you?