# How can I import JSON data into PostgreSQL with psql?

Tags: json, postgresql, psql

PostgreSQL has a lot of functions for working with JSON data. However, it seems to be difficult to import JSON data, since the COPY command does not support JSON.

Assuming I have a file named `data.json` that contains JSON data like the following:

```
[
  {"id":1, "name": "Jakob"},
  {"id":2, "name": "Klara"}
]
```

Is there a simple way to import that JSON data file just using psql?

Comment: If it's a one time project, I would use a JSON to CSV converter, then use the copy command per normal. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130849/convert-json-format-to-csv-format-for-ms-excel

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSV format to import arbitry data, as long as you quote it correctly. You can use cat & sed to quote your CSV file:

```
cat data.json | sed 's/"/""/g' | cat <(echo '"') - <(echo '"')
```

The first cat command reads the file, the sed command replaces all double quotes with two double quotes, and the final cat puts a double quote before and after the json.

Let's create a table on the server:

```
psql -c 'CREATE TABLE import(data jsonb)'
```

You can now use the result of this command with psql:

```
cat data.json | sed 's/"/""/g' | cat <(echo '"') - <(echo '"') | \
 psql -c 'COPY import(data) FROM STDIN (FORMAT CSV)'
```