# Export json array to an excel file (server or client side)

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx, filesaver.js

To export json array to an excel file, 
taking in mind big amount of data and performance, which approach is preferred:

1. Generate the file in the back end and download it.
2. Generate the file on the client side (Browser) using a library like XLSX to convert json array to excel.

Comment: I think you can visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130849/convert-json-format-to-csv-format-for-ms-excel)

Answer (score 1):

Out of your 2 options it should be on backend side. But what I suggest is that if you are expecting that there will be huge data then you keep on sending 100s or 1000s of records in chunk and create the file in backend. And once it is done you can download entire file.