# How to export desired fields from PHP array to JSON/CSV in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, export-to-csv

I'm a newbie about php and javascript and sorry for my bad English. I've searched and read many threads about this but nothing works for me.

I need to understand how I can export some fields of a json files into a CSV or excel with some of that fields and not all, ready to download.

I managed to get a json output with an array of data and print it in the console by clicking on a button. This is a script inside a php file.
Now I need to convert this output in CSV and able to download it.

Here js code where I stored the array in var json :

```
            <a id="csv_btn" class= "btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" 
             
            onclick="download_csv()">Download CSV</a>

            <div class="js-search-box"></div>
    
        
<script type="text/javascript">

                var json = <?php echo json_encode($outjson); ?>;
                
                function download_csv () {
                var formId = document.getElementById("csv_btn");
                window.alert("Do yow want to download CSV?");
    
                console.log(json);
        
            }
                     
</script>
```

In the images attached, there is the output after clicking on download.

Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://medium.com/@danny.pule/export-json-to-csv-file-using-javascript-a0b7bc5b00d2)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbTCE.png)

**EDIT:**

After many attempts, I've found a code working quite well; thanks to Danny Pule found at [this link](https://medium.com/@danny.pule/export-json-to-csv-file-using-javascript-a0b7bc5b00d2)

Now, I'm trying to figure out how to create a filter to exclude or include certain fields and get the CSV with the wanted fields. Also, if someone could explain me how to extract data from a field that print [object Object] inside this json file (i.e. at "machine" field there is another array)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbTCE.png)

The code below:

```
<!--gabri-->
            
            <a id="csv_btn" class= "btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" onclick="exportCSVFile(headers, itemsFormatted, fileTitle)">Download CSV</a>

            <div class="js-search-box"></div>
                    
        
<script type="text/javascript">

                var datajson = <?php echo json_encode($outjson); ?>;
                
                //download_csv(datajson);
        
                function convertToCSV(objArray) {
                    
                     var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
                    
                    window.alert("Do yow want to download CSV?");
                     
                     var str = '';
                     
                     for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                            var line = '';
                            for (var index in array[i]) {
                                if (line != '') line += ','
                    
                                line += array[i][index];
                            }
                    
                            str += line + '\r\n';
                        }
                    
                        return str;


                    }

                function exportCSVFile(headers, items, fileTitle) {
                    if (headers) {
                        items.unshift(headers);
                    }
                
                    // Convert Object to JSON
                    var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items);
                
                    var csv = this.convertToCSV(jsonObject);
                
                    var exportedFilenmae = fileTitle + '.csv' || 'export.csv';
                
                    var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
                    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
                        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, exportedFilenmae);
                    } else {
                        var link = document.createElement("a");
                        if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
                            // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
                            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                            link.setAttribute("href", url);
                            link.setAttribute("download", exportedFilenmae);
                            link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                            document.body.appendChild(link);
                            link.click();
                            document.body.removeChild(link);
                            console.log(datajson);
                        }
                    }
                }

var headers = {
    label: 'Project Name'.replace(/,/g, ''), // remove commas to avoid errors
    id: "id".replace(/,/g, ''),
    active: "active",
    start_date: "Start Date".replace(/,/g, ''),
    year:"Year",
    coord: "Coord",
    perc: "perc",
    plants:"Total Plants",
    done: "Plants done",
    machine: "Machine"
};

//itemsNotFormatted = [];

var obj = JSON.parse([datajson]);
var values = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; });
//var values = Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => { console.log(key, obj[key]);});
console.log(values);

var itemsFormatted = values;

// format the data
/*itemsNotFormatted.forEach((item) => {
    itemsFormatted.push({
       label: item.label.replace(/,/g, ''), // remove commas to avoid errors,
        id: item.id,
        start_date: item.start_date,
        coord: item.coord,
        perc: item.perc,
        plants: item.plants,
        done: item.done,
        machine: item.machine
    });
});
*/
var fileTitle = 'monitor-report'; // or 'my-unique-title'

//exportCSVFile(headers, itemsFormatted, fileTitle); // call the exportCSVFile() function to process the JSON and trigger the download
                    
   
</script>
```

This is the datajson I get from php

```
[{"label":"garbuiodiadoragrande","id":2176216,"active":0,"start_date":"23 mag, 2018","end_date":null,"perc":0.061996280223187,"plants":1613,"done":1,"machines":[{"label":"Trattore test 02 2016","id":3003}],"client":null,"client_id":null,"source":{"label":"Trattore test 02 2016","id":3003},"center_lat":45.777920164083,"center_lon":12.007139535756,"page":"\/customer\/projects\/2176216\/"},{"label":"prova","id":2176008,"active":0,"start_date":"21 mag, 2018","end_date":null,"perc":0.44247787610619,"plants":3842,"done":17,"machines":[{"label":"Trattore test 02 2016","id":3003}],"client":null,"client_id":null,"source":{"label":"Trattore test 02 2016","id":3003},"center_lat":43.830309706033,"center_lon":11.206148940511,"page":"\/customer\/projects\/2176008\/"}
```

and in the image attached below is the result I got from Object.map in the console.log (values),  but I'm not sure to be in the right way and I'm quite confused.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AOxV.png)
Thanks for any suggestions

**EDIT:**
Ok, I got a code working and filtering the desired field

```
                <script type="text/javascript">


                    Date.prototype.today = function () { 
                        return ((this.getDate() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getDate() +"/"+(((this.getMonth()+1) < 10)?"0":"") + (this.getMonth()+1) +"/"+ this.getFullYear();
                    }

                    // For the time now
                    Date.prototype.timeNow = function () {
                        return ((this.getHours() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getHours() +":"+ ((this.getMinutes() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getMinutes() +":"+ ((this.getSeconds() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getSeconds();
                    }


                    var datetime = " @ " + new Date().today() + " @ " + new Date().timeNow();
                    var fileTitle = 'monitor-report'+ datetime; // or 'my-unique-title'
                    var datajson = <?php echo json_encode($outjson); ?>;
                    var itemsFormatted = JSON.parse([datajson]);

                    
                    
                    //download_csv(datajson);
                    
                    function convertToCSV(objArray) {
                        
                        var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

                        window.alert("Do yow want to download CSV?");
                        
                        var str = '';

                        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                            var line = '';
                            for (var index in array[i]) {
                                if (line != '') line += ','

                                    line += array[i][index];
                            }
                            
                            str += line + '\r\n';
                        }
                        
                        return str;


                    }

                    function exportCSVFile(headers, items, fileTitle) {
                        if (headers) {
                            items.unshift(headers);
                        }
                        
                        // Convert Object to JSON
                        var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items,
                            ['label',
                            'id',
                            'start_date',
                            'year',
                            'end_date',
                            'perc',
                            'plants',
                            'done']);

                        
                        var csv = this.convertToCSV(jsonObject);
                        
                        var exportedFilenmae = fileTitle + '.csv' || 'export.csv';
                        
                        var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
                        if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
                            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, exportedFilenmae);
                        } else {
                            var link = document.createElement("a");
                            if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
                                // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
                                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                                link.setAttribute("href", url);
                                link.setAttribute("download", exportedFilenmae);
                                link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                                document.body.appendChild(link);
                                link.click();
                                document.body.removeChild(link);
                                console.log(jsonObject);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    var headers = {
                                    label: 'Project Name'.replace(/,/g, ''), // remove commas to avoid errors
                                    id: "id",
                                    active: "active",
                                    start_date: "Start Date".replace(/,/g, ''),
                                    year:"Year",
                                    end_date:"End Date",
                                    perc: "perc",
                                    coord: "Coord",
                                    plants:"Total Plants",
                                    done: "Plants done",
                                };
                                
                    //console.log(datajson);


                </script>
```

But I can't figured out how to extract another array inside the main array. Here in "machines":[{"label":"Trattore test 02 2016","id":3003}], I need label and id.
Anyone could help me)

```
[{"label":"garbuio diadoragrande","id":2176216,"active":0,"start_date":"23 mag,2018",
"end_date":null,"perc":0.061996280223187,"plants":1613,"done":1,
"machines":[{"label":"Trattore test 02 2016","id":3003}],
"client":null,"client_id":null,"source":{"label":"Trattore test 02 2016","id":3003},"center_lat":45.777920164083,"center_lon":12.007139535756,"page":"\/customer\/projects\/2176216\/"},
```

Comment: You need to write some code to convert the desired part of the JSON to a CSV file. Downloading is not a difficult thing to acheive.

Comment: Hi thank you Charlie, I know that it needs some code but what I've tried did't work. I'll post what I've found to share and find what's wrong

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130849/convert-json-format-to-csv-format-for-ms-excel

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem, or a JS problem?

Comment: Hi, Tiff. Thanks for your suggestion. I've already read this thread and the last code I've update is a version combined by Danny Pule and it works. Now I looking for a solution for get data from array inside other array and create a filter to choose fields to print in CSV

Comment: Hi,@NicoHaase. Thanks for you reply. The problem is that I'm a newbie in javascript. I've edit the post and I've update the code. Now I would like to know ho to extract data from the array inside another array. In the last image you can see in "machine" field that there is another array. The result in CSV is [object Object] How can I extract data from there? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a working code. Probably it's not perfect but it works!
Here is the code if it might be useful for someone.

Thanks to the community

```
<script type="text/javascript">


                    Date.prototype.today = function () { 
                        return ((this.getDate() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getDate() +"/"+(((this.getMonth()+1) < 10)?"0":"") + (this.getMonth()+1) +"/"+ this.getFullYear();
                    }

                    // For the time now
                    Date.prototype.timeNow = function () {
                        return ((this.getHours() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getHours() +":"+ ((this.getMinutes() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getMinutes() +":"+ ((this.getSeconds() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getSeconds();
                    }


                    var datetime = " @ " + new Date().today() + " @ " + new Date().timeNow();
                    var fileTitle = 'Report_Monitor'+ datetime; // or 'my-unique-title'

                    var datajson = <?php echo json_encode($outjson); ?>;
                    var itemsFormatted = JSON.parse([datajson]);

                    //var itemsFormatted = obj;

                    
                    
                    function convertToCSV(objArray) {
                        
                        var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

                        window.alert("Do yow want to download CSV?");
                        
                        var str = '';

                        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                            var line = '';
                            for (var index in array[i]) {
                                if (line != '') line += ','

                                    line += array[i][index];
                            }
                            
                            str += line + '\r\n';
                        }
                        
                        return str;


                    }

                    function exportCSVFile(headers, items, fileTitle) {
                        if (headers) {
                            items.unshift(headers);
                        }
                        
                        // Convert Object to JSON
                        var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items,
                            ['label',
                            'id',
                            "start_date".replace(/,/g, ' '),
                            'end_date',
                            'perc',
                            'plants',
                            'done',
                            'center_lat',
                            'center_lon']);


                        var jsonObjectFiltered = jsonObject.replace(/,(?!["{}[\]])/g, "");

                        console.log(jsonObjectFiltered);
                        
                        var csv = this.convertToCSV(jsonObjectFiltered).replace(/null/g,"0");
                        
                        var exportedFilenmae = fileTitle + '.csv' || 'export.csv';
                        
                        var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
                        if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
                            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, exportedFilenmae);
                        } else {
                            var link = document.createElement("a");
                            if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
                                // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
                                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                                link.setAttribute("href", url);
                                link.setAttribute("download", exportedFilenmae);
                                link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                                document.body.appendChild(link);
                                link.click();
                                document.body.removeChild(link);
                                console.log(jsonObject);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    var headers = {
                                    label: 'Project Name', // remove commas to avoid errors
                                    id: 'id',
                                    active: 'active',
                                    start_date: 'Start Date',
                                    //year:'Year',
                                    end_date:'End Date',
                                    perc: 'Percentage',
                                    plants:'Total Stakes',
                                    done: 'Stakes Done',
                                    center_lat: 'Lat',
                                    center_lon: 'Lon'
                                };

                    //console.log(datajson);


                </script>
```