# TypeError: string indices must be integers Work & Doesnt work

Tags: python, json, loops

I have been looping the the data, all of them are the same, the first loop works well but when it hits the 2nd loop, it receive that error.

Any idea how I can debug this issue?

I suspect the issue is on the item_id, do i convert it to string or is there any advice anyone could provide. It would be greatly appreciated

```
payload = {'item': r.json()['account']['item'],'item_id': loop['item_id']}
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should add what `r.json()` returns and the value of `loop`.

Comment: Post the whole loop code.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why am I seeing "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers) See specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6077692/1110381). Seriously, read the error message, try to understand it, if you don't understand it, google for an explanation. There are thousands of questions out there with excactly the same error, and many posts explaining why this exception happens.

Comment: Any workaround would depend on _what you actually want to achieve_ and _what the data actually represents_. All we can do with the information you've shown is tell you why you get that error and how to prevent it. What you're supposed to do is _debug your program and think for yourself_; obviously you're expecting a different structure than the one you actually get so the first thing to do would be finding out how exactly the structure differs from your expectations. Once you've found that out the rest should follow logically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `r.json()['account']` returns a string, and when you add another `[]` afterwards, you're trying to index into it as though it were a dictionary. That's okay when you use an integer as the index (`str[1]` returns the second character, for instance), but it won't work here because your index is a word. In other words, what you think is a dictionary is really a string.

Comment: But i mean that's the data, how else am i suppose to read it?

Comment: You could print it. The point is, the data isn't in the form you're expecting, so your logic can't process it. In this situation, I usually just dump the whole thing (print the JSON as a string) and step by step, try to figure out why it's not working. I think your first record must be {account: {item: 5}} and the second record is {account: "hello world"}, for example. But you need to print it to see.

Comment: Or the code before your function is not processing it correctly. It's possible that at one level the input is correct, but it's not getting parsed into nested data structures. That is, "{item: 5}" could be being left as a string instead of parsed into a JSON structure (it should be a dictionary with a string key and a numeric value).