# python and json, Error - TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python

I Learn kivy for making android app. so I read the 'Creating Apps in Kivy' book.
I encountered into error when I follow instructions.

My python code is below.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
import json
import urllib
import urllib.request
import codecs

class AddLocationForm(BoxLayout):

    search_input = ObjectProperty()
    search_results = ObjectProperty()


    def search_location(self):
        search_template = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/' + 'weather?q={}&&APPID=d9733213314ecfdbd08f9753d38444bf'
        search_url = search_template.format(self.search_input.text)
        u = urllib.request.urlopen(search_url)
        data = u.read().decode('utf-8')
        print(type(data))
        # request = UrlRequest(search_url, self.found_location)
        self.found_location(data)

    def found_location(self, data):
        # reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
        data2 = json.loads(data)
        # data2 = reader(data).json()
        print(data2)
        for i in data2:
            cities = ['{} ({})'.format(i['name'],i['sys']['country'])]
            self.search_results.item_strings = cities

class WeatherApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WeatherApp().run()
```

And my Error is

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "E:\Weather\main.py", line 52, in <module>
     WeatherApp().run()
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 828, in run
 runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 487, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 619, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 362, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 330, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 315, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 221, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:7699)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1030, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
  File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:7699)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line  1046, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:7699)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 432, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:7699)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 432, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch  (kivy\_event.c:7699)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line  110, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 714, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch   (kivy\_event.c:7654)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1224, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch   (kivy\_event.c:13497)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1108, in    kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy\_event.c:12329)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1557, in     custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "E:\Weather\weather.kv", line 89, in <module>
 on_press: root.search_location()
   File "E:\Weather\main.py", line 35, in search_location
 self.found_location(data)
   File "E:\Weather\main.py", line 43, in found_location
     cities = ['{} ({})'.format(i['name'],i['sys']['country'])]
 TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

And json content is

```
{
"coord":{"lon":-123.12,"lat":49.25},
"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clearsky","icon":"02n"}],
"base":"stations",
"main":{"temp":265.29,"pressure":1022,"humidity":73,"temp_min":263.15,"temp_max":267.15    },
"visibility":48279,
"wind":{"speed":2.6,"deg":80},"clouds":{"all":5},"dt":1484230500,
"sys":{"type":1,"id":3359,"message":0.0149,"country":"CA","sunrise":1484237006,"sunset":1484267964},
"id":6173331,"name":"Vancouver","cod":200}
```

How can I solve it??

Comment: `data2` is a `dict` holding 1 record. `for i in data2` iterates its keys, which are strings.

Comment: `print(i)` and you'll see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You are only getting 1 record as a dict so you don't need the loop.

```
def found_location(self, data):
    # reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
    data2 = json.loads(data)
    # data2 = reader(data).json()
    print(data2)
    cities = ['{} ({})'.format(data2['name'],data2['sys']['country'])]
    self.search_results.item_strings = cities
```

Comment: I got anthoer Error :  TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Good! I was puzzling over the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're taking the indice of a string, not the dictionary that you think you are, here

```
for i in data2:
    cities = ['{} ({})'.format(i['name'],i['sys']['country'])]
    self.search_results.item_strings = cities
```

As tdelaney mentioned in the comments, you're iterating through the dict and then trying to take the indice of a string inside of it.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers) as well.