# How to print dictionary from list "Python":

Tags: python

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}

students = ["lloyd","alice","tyler"]


#Accessing Dictionary from List

print students[0]['name']
```

Expected out is : Lloyd

whenever I run the above code I get this error,

```
===============================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 30, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers 
===============================================
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers

Comment: students = [lloyd] not students = ["lloyd"]

Comment: Read the error message: The error message means that string indices must be integers. The only index that isn't is `'name'`. So it probably means that `students[0]` is a string (print it to see what it is). Other than that it's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Probably not what you wanted (or what you should want), but you could do `print locals()[students[0]]['name']`.

Answer (score 3):

it's because students contains just strings ["lloyd","alice","tyler"]

```
print students[0]
>> "lloyd"
```

maybe you wanted to do this:

```
students = [lloyd]
```

then

```
print students[0]['name']
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

You may want to place the dictionaries in the list rather than just the string names.

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}

alice = {"name": "Alice "}
tyler = {"name": "Tyler "}

students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]

print students[0]['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command:

```
print students[0]
```

It will give your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `students` is just a list of strings. So the value of `students[0]` is a string, `'lloyd'`, which is distinct from the dictionary you created with the name `lloyd`.

I think you want `students` to be a list of dictionaries. Below I've shown how to do that, and created empty dictionaries for `alice` and `tyler`. Then simply take the quotes away from your declaration of `students` to store the dictionaries instead of strings with the same names, and your last line works.

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}

alice = {"name": "Alice"}

tyler = {"name": "Tyler"}

students = [lloyd,alice,tyler]

print students[0]['name']
```

which gives:

```
Lloyd
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the dictionary lloyd defined at the top. When you create your list with students = ["lloyd","alice","tyler"], you are instead using the string "lloyd".
So students[0] returns this string instead of the dict.

You need to use students = [lloyd,alice,tyler]. You might also want to create a dict for alice and tyler.

Answer (score 0):

What you have tried is almost correct. You got an error because "string indices must be integers". So you can use eval() method in python ([python-eval-method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)).

try the following code

```
lloyd = {
"name": "Lloyd",
"homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
"quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
"tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
students = ["lloyd","alice","tyler"]
#Accessing Dictionary from List
print eval(students[0])['name']
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

your `students` list contains just `str` objects.

```
print students[0]
>> "lloyd"
```

as you can see we got `str` object type.

you should fix it with this usage and **removal** of the the quotes:

```
students = [lloyd]
print students[0]['name']
```

Done ! :)

Even better to use the `get` method for dict usage:

```
print students[0].get('name')
```