# how to make string indices into integers instead of strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to open some 18 h5 files from the local directory by using datetime function in python. I have access some data inside those files and so, I use numpy arrays. I am getting this type error while trying to access one of the temperature arrays in the  h5 files.
can I have any solution?
thanks in advance

```
indir = os.chdir('H:\INSAT-3D\may12')
dt = datetime.datetime(2016,5,12,0,0,0,tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
tdelta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)
dt = dt+tdelta
f= dt.strftime('3DSND_%d%b%Y_%H%M_L1B_SA1.h5')
f=f.upper()
print f

new = []
abc=0
for names in range(0,24):
    tdelta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)
    dt = dt+tdelta
    f = dt.strftime('3DSND_%d%b%Y_%H%M_L1B_SA1.h5')
    f= f.upper()
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        read = h5py.File(f, 'r')
        temp = np.array(f['SND_MWIR1_TEMP'])
```

here is the error I am getting,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-2fe7a4d4ceb7> in <module>()
     22     if os.path.isfile(f):
     23         read = h5py.File(f, 'r')
---> 24         temp = np.array(f['SND_MWIR1_TEMP'])
     25 
     26 

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: See [this explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6077692/4391450)

Comment: It looks like you possibly want to use `read['SND_MWIR1_TEMP']` instead of `f['SND_MWIR1_TEMP']`.

Comment: Thanx for the help. Though it eliminates the error, doesn't show the MWIR1_TEMP as an array like numpy array does. Is there any approach helps me to get it as an array itself?