# TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str in python

Tags: python

Here is my python code, Which is throwing error while executing.

```
def split_cell(s):
    a = s.split(".")
    b = a[1].split("::=")
    return (a[0].lower(),b[0].lower(),b[1].lower())

logic_tbl,logic_col,logic_value = split_cell(rules['logic_1'][ith_rule])
mems = logic_tbl[logic_tbl[logic_col]==logic_value]['mbr_id'].tolist()
```

Function split_cell is working fine, and all the columns in logic_tbl are of object datatypes.

HEre is the Traceback
[image]

Comment: Kindly include the complete error traceback.

Comment: Did you not get a solution from all the questions with the same title that were suggested when you asked this?

Comment: What are the type of `logic_tbl[0]` and `logic_tbl[1]`? Can you print the `logic_tbl` after that function call

Comment: and what is `logic_col`

Comment: I think the problem is: `logic_tbl[logic_col]` because `logic_col` is a string

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil updated please check

Comment: @cricket_007, Yes I did check couple of links, Didn't get solution

Comment: @kuro: In the split_cell function, I am returning them as strings. Should it not be like this, Please suggest!

Comment: @depperm I din't understand! if logic_col is a string any problem because of this? Please suggest!

Comment: `logic_col` is a string and thus can't be used as index for `logic_tbl`. Indices should always be integer in case of strings

Comment: @kuro https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT5Nc.png , please check this, First three lines are columns in logic_tbl, and (....) is the value the split_cell function returns,  I printed other variables, that has empty pd series, you please ignore that! and the Traceback!;;;;;;; we refer like a['b'] when b is variable name in dataframe a , isn't it? please suggest!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I seeing "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers)

Comment: @depperm But it is involved json and csv, But this is in pandas dataframes, In this case how i do convert variable name to int?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this corrected!

Logic_tbl contains name of pandas dataframe

Logic_col contains name of column name in the pandas dataframe

logic_value contains value of the rows in the logic_col variable in logic_tbl dataframe.

```
mems = logic_tbl[logic_tbl[logic_col]==logic_value]['mbr_id'].tolist()
```

I was trying like above, But python treating logic_tbl as string, not doing any pandas dataframe level operations.

```
So, I had created a dictionary like this 
dt_dict={}
dt_dict['a_med_clm_diag'] = a_med_clm_diag
```

And modified my code as below,

```
mems = dt_dict[logic_tbl][dt_dict[logic_tbl][logic_col]==logic_value]['mbr_id'].tolist()
```

This is working as expected. I come to this idea when i wrote like,

```
mems = logic_tbl[logic_tbl[logic_col]==logic_value,'mbr_id']
```

And this throwed message like,"'logic_tbl' is a string Nothing to filter".

Answer (score -1):

Try writing that last statement like below code:

```
filt = numpy.array[a==logic_value for a in logic_col]
mems = [i for indx,i in enumerate(logic_col) if filt[indx] == True]
```

Does this work?

Comment: If that does not work... then please try this too:
filt = numpy.array[a==logic_value for a in logic_col];
mems = [i for indx,i in enumerate(logic_col) if filt[indx] == True]

Comment: logic_col is a variable name in pandas dataframe and logic_value is the value for one of the rows in logic_col, These two never be equals.

Comment: Shouldn't logic_col be a numpy array