# “ string indices must be integers” when reading Twitter JSON object into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, tweepy

I have a JSON object, retrieved from Twitter API through tweepy that contains the twitter object, looking like this:

```
{"created_at": "Tue Aug 01 16:23:56 +0000 2017",
 "id": xxx,
 "id_str": “xxx”,
 "full_text": “xxxxx”,
 "truncated": false,
 "display_text_range": [0, 85], 
 "entities": {"hashtags": [], "symbols": [], "user_mentions": [], "urls": [], 
 "media": [{"id": xxxx, "id_str": “xxxxx”, "indices": [86, 109], 
 "media_url": “xxxxx”, Etc…..
```

I am trying to read three values into a dataframe

```
df_tweet = []
for json_string in json_str:

    tweet_id = json_string['id']
    retweet_count = json_string['retweet_count']
    favorite_count = json_string['favorite_count']

    df_tweet.append({'tweet_id':int(id),
                    'retweet_count':int(retweet_count),
                    'favorite_count':int(favorite_count)
                 })
```

I get the error“ string indices must be integers”.  I understand that “id” and the other values  in the JSON response are not an index and I can’t read out the data like this.
Reading this question: [Why am I seeing "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers)
Is there anything that can be done at this point, or do I need to make changes on how I get the JSON in the first place?

Comment: Why do you even use a `for` loop?

Comment: What is the output of `type(json_string)`? It seems `str`, and this may be why you are getting the error.

Comment: Not quite sure why I used the for loop, to be honest. Will try to read it to a dataframe without the loop.

Comment: You may need to use a dictionary

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I went a different approach in getting the data from API and ended up with a list of dictionaries which was easy to use. Not sure how I can close this question.