# python 'string indices must be integers' when try parse json

Tags: python, twitter

When i try to read json file

```
for index, js in enumerate(json_files):
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)) as json_file:
        json_text = json.load(json_file)
        t_id = json_text["id"]
        created_at = json_text["created_at"]
        text = json_text["text"]
        user_name = json_text["user"]["name"]
        location = json_text["user"]["location"]
        jsons_data.loc[index] = [t_id,created_at,text,user_name,location]
```

i got this error

TypeError: string indices must be integers

this are in my json file

```
"{\"created_at\":\"Wed Nov 07 06:01:26 +0000 2018\",\"id\":1060049570195853312,\"id_str\":\"1060049570195853312\",\"text\":\"RT @maulinaantika: Tempe Khot News:\\nDiduga pertemuan kontrak politik antara Polri &amp; timses jokowi tahun 2014\\n\\nDalam foto tersebut terlihat\\u2026\",\"source\":\"\\u003ca href=\\\"https:\\/\\/mobile.twitter.com\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\"\\u003eTwitter Lite\\u003c\\/a\\u003e\",\"truncated\"
```

when i try like this

```
with open('tm.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        text = line.encode("utf-8")
        json_text = json.loads(text)

print(json_text)
```

i got this result

```
{"created_at":"Sat Dec 08 12:58:14 +0000 2018","id":1071388484609413120,...
```

can someone guide me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I seeing "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers)

Comment: @Dinari cant find my answer there

Comment: Always include the complete error traceback in your question. Also, see how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest explanation for *Why do I get this error* considering your code is:

> ```
> json_text = json.load(json_file)
> ```

is providing you with a string. Which you try to use like a dictionary:

> ```
>  t_id = json_text["id"]
>  created_at = json_text["created_at"]
>  text = json_text["text"]
>  user_name = json_text["user"]["name"]
>  location = json_text["user"]["location"]
> ```

You can use `try: ... except Exception as e: ...` to avoid this and get the name of your json that is the culprit. Then you can fix your json data:

```
for index, js in enumerate(json_files):
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)) as json_file:
        json_text = json.load(json_file)
        try:
            t_id = json_text["id"]
            created_at = json_text["created_at"]
            text = json_text["text"]
            user_name = json_text["user"]["name"]
            location = json_text["user"]["location"]
            jsons_data.loc[index] = [t_id,created_at,text,user_name,location]
        except TypeError as te:
            print("Bad json - not a dict: ", os.path.join(path_to_json, js))
            print("Json was deserialized into a : ", type(json_text) )
            break # exit while, fix your data, do until it works
```

---

See:

- [PyTut: Handling exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)