# "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str" during boto3 aws execution

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

I am trying to get AWS' VM list using Boto3's `describe_instance` method. I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pySkynet2.py", line 238, in <module>
    skynet.execute()
  File "pySkynet2.py", line 126, in execute
    self.verify('build')
  File "pySkynet2.py", line 77, in verify
    vm_list = self.cloud_forge.get_vm_list()
  File "/Users/ssrini358/workplace/Codes/COM_codes/Skynet/api2/cloudforge.py", line 952, in get_vm_list
    instance = self.get_instance(auto_instance['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['InstanceId'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Following is the code snippet.

```
    def get_vm_list(self):
        """
        look up all the instances for the cluster (autoscaling_group)
        :return: a list of associative arrays containing the instance_id, ip address and host name
        """
        try:
            instances = self.get_instances_for_autoscaling_group()
            vms = []
            for auto_instance in instances:
                instance = self.get_instance(auto_instance['Reservations'][0],['Instances'][0],['InstanceId'])
                host_name = ''
                for tag in instance['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['Tags']:
                    if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
                        host_name = tag['Value']
                        break

                vms.append({'instance_id': instance['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['InstanceId'],
                            'ip_addr': instance['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['PrivateIpAddress'],
                            'host_name': host_name})

            return vms
```

I have tried ['Reservations'][0], as well. But I am not able to get the instanceId. 
Kindly help
TIA

Comment: did you check the type and value of `instances`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I seeing "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be like this since you already assigned the instance?

```
instances = self.get_instances_for_autoscaling_group()
vms = []
for auto_instance in instances:
    instance = self.get_instance(auto_instance['Reservations'][0],['Instances'][0],['InstanceId'])
    host_name = ''
    for tag in instance:
```

Comment: I have tried this as well. Still getting the same error

Comment: ```
    instance = self.get_instance(auto_instance['Reservations'][0],['Instances'][0],['InstanceId'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```