# Python extracting JSON dictionary TypeError

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I am using [this Python project](https://github.com/BensonHsu/SBrick-Framework) to try and interact with my Lego SBrick.

If I use the following piece of code (once connected to the SBrick):

```
json_response = client.rr_get_adc(sbrick_id='11:22:33:44:55:66', timeout=5)
```

I can then print the json_response to give me:

```
{"ret_code": 100, "temperature": 42.53253535, "voltage": 8.3954548125663}
```

I want to access the "ret_code" to check it equals 100 but if I try:

```
print (json_response["ret_code"])
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How can I pull the ret_code as an integer?

Comment: Have you tried *parsing* the JSON?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I seeing "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks jonrsharpe.

I added:

```
result = json.loads(json_response)
```

Then I was able to access the ret_code with:

```
result["ret_code"]
```