# How to search substring in python?

Tags: python, file, find

I want to search through a text file and output substrings that match the user input, but when my program searches each line I want it to only search the characters between the "|" character and the end of the line. But I keep getting the following error:

Comment: You should use a context manager to handle files. Are you using Python 2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I seeing "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use slices. Just replace `,` with `:` in your code:

```
y = line[char_pos:x]
```