# How to get a value from my JSON file, in python

Tags: python, json

I want you to ask for your help.

I need to browse folder with json files and I need to search for one attribute with specific value.

Here is my code:

```
def listDir():
fileNames = os.listdir(FOLDER_PATH)
for fileName in fileNames:
    print(fileName)
    with open('C:\\Users\\Kamčo\\Desktop\\UBLjsons\\' + fileName, 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        data_json = json.dumps(data, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
        print(data_json)
        for line in data_json:
            if line['ID'] == 'Kamilko':
                print("try") #just to be sure it accessed to this
```

I am getting this error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

I also tried to search for a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers) but it didnt help me.

Here is my JSON

```
{
"Invoice": {
    "@xmlns": "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2",
    "@xmlns:cac": "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2",
    "@xmlns:cbc": "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2",
    "ID": "Kamilko",
    "IssueDate": "2020-02-09",
    "OrderReference": {
      "ID": "22"
     },
    "InvoiceLine": {
      "Price": {
        "PriceAmount": {
          "@currencyID": "EUR",
          "#text": "23.50"
         },
        "BaseQuantity": {
          "@unitCode": "C62",
          "#text": "1"
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Why do you immediately reserialize the data with `json.dumps`?

Comment: You should be working with `data`, not `data_json`.

Comment: thanks guys, working with data helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've loaded your file in using `json.load(...)`. That'll convert the JSON data into a Python dictionary that you can use to access elements:

```
if data["Invoice"]["OrderReference"]["ID"] == 22:
   print("try")
```

Note that you might want to check the relevant keys exist along the way, in case the structure of your file varies, or you could catch the `KeyError` that'll come up if the key doesn't exist, using `try/except`.

**Some more background:**

When you then call `json.dumps(...)`, you're taking that handy python structure and converting it back into a hard-to-understand string again. I don't think you want or need to do this.

The specific error you have is because `dumps` has created a string. You're then trying to access an element of that string using the `[ ]` operator. Strings can only be indexed using integers, e.g. `mystr[4]`, so Python doesn't understand what you're asking it to do with `data_json["ID"]`.