# JSON TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python

I get the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers" in the following code.

```py
import json

import requests

url = "https://petition.parliament.uk/petitions/300139.json"

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
parsed = json.loads(data)

sig_count = data["attributes"]["signature_count"]

print(sig_count)
```

Comment: You mean `sig_count = parsed["attributes"]["signature_count"]`

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. If you're using requests, don't waste time with the `json.loads()` and just call `response.json()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I seeing "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

url = 'https://petition.parliament.uk/petitions/300139.json'

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text

parsed = json.loads(data)

sig_count = parsed["data"]["attributes"]["signature_count"]

print(sig_count)
```

you are calling the variable data instead of parsed. You are also missing the "data" key when filtering.

Answer (score 2):

After using `json.loads()`, you need to use the newly defined variable because the opreration does not happen in place. data` is the json in its raw form, interpreted as a string.

Try with:

`parsed['attributes']['signature_count']`