# TypeError: string indices must be integers when using json file in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to count the number of national holidays `N` in each city in a `.json` file and I keep getting the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

I've read a bunch of other posts about this error and I can't really find anything that helps. I'm assuming its related to how I'm pulling the `.json` file?
(encoding for non-english letters in file)

```
import json

world_hol_data = json.load(open("holiday_data.json", "r", encoding="utf8"))


total_national_hol = 0

for cont in world_hol_data:
    for city in cont:
        if city["type"] == "N":
            total_national_hol += 1
print(total_national_hol)
```

Comment: Welcome. In your loop `city` is `str` and you're trying to process it like `dict`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. As an aside, you should use a context manager to handle file objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I seeing "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please first check your data variable to see what you received there. I guess at least a list containing with string whereas it should be a list of dictionaries.