# Python:TypeError string indices must be integers

Tags: python

While working with a REST API, I am getting an error like this.

```
TypeError string indices must be integers
```

My code:

```py
response = table.get_item(
    Key={'facility_id': str(facility_id)}
)
if "Item" in response.keys():
    returnvals['status'] = 1
    item = response['Item']
    for item in response["Item"]:
        result.append({"facility_id": item["facility_id"],
        result.append({"facility_id": item["facility_id"],
                       "facility_name": item["facility_name"],
                       "display_units": item["display_units"],
                       "created_by": item["created_by"],
                       "created_date": item["created_date"],
        })

    returnvals['params'] = result
```

The line on which I am getting error is

```
 result.append({"facility_id": item["facility_id"],
```

What's causing this?

Comment: What is the type of `item`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I seeing "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers)

Comment: it is dictionary

Comment: Does `response["Item"]` return a list of items? Or is it a dictionary?

Comment: `item = response['Item']` doesn't really do anything if you then go on to reassign `item` to each element *in* `response['Item']`.

Comment: item is probably a string. Unless its a dict or json (in context of requests) the above thing would not work.

Comment: You *think* `item` is a `dict`. The interpreter says it is a string. In such cases the sensible thing to do is print `item` to find out why the interpreter disagrees with you. It is correct, whatever you may think.

Answer (score 0):

The error above :

> TypeError string indices must be integers

and as you have mentioned in your question that the error is in the line below

> result.append({"facility_id":item["facility_id"],

Hence, I guess that item is a string here. However, you treat it as a dictionary object and that is causing the issue.