# convert nested json to dataframe using json_normalize in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to convert nested json to dataframe.

The result i want  to get :

```
| securityFullTypeCode | securityTypeDesc |
| - - - - - - - - - - -| - - - - - - - - -|
| 0101                 |  Ordinary Share  |
| 0102                 |  Preferred  Share|
```

I tried json_normalize but unsuccessfully.

Json file looks like this :

```
{
    "securitiesTypes": {
        "result": [
            {
                "securityFullTypeCode": "0101",
                "securityTypeDesc": "Ordinary Share"
            },
            {
                "securityFullTypeCode": "0102",
                "securityTypeDesc": "Preferred  Share"
            },
            {
                "securityFullTypeCode": "0103",
                "securityTypeDesc": "Preferr & Cum  share"
            }
        ],
        "total": 215
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: try : `pd.DataFrame(pd.read_json(file.json').loc['result','securitiesTypes'])`

Comment: @anky nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked in: [JSON to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe)

The following seems to do the trick:

```py
file = {
    "securitiesTypes": {
        "result": [
            {
                "securityFullTypeCode": "0101",
                "securityTypeDesc": "Ordinary Share"
            },
            {
                "securityFullTypeCode": "0102",
                "securityTypeDesc": "Preferred  Share"
            },
            {
                "securityFullTypeCode": "0103",
                "securityTypeDesc": "Preferr & Cum  share"
            }
        ],
        "total": 215
    }
}

df = pd.json_normalize(file['securitiesTypes']['result'])
```

What problems are you running into exactly?

Comment: I got the following error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I would check out the following in that case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_normalize` with `record_path` option:

```
import json

with open('file.json') as f:
    df = pd.json_normalize(json.load(f), 
                           record_path=['securitiesTypes','result']
                          )
```