# TypeError: string indices must be integers; how can I fix this problem in my code?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to go through all cells from a CSV, from the column 'Text', and to make a new column named 'Type' where I'll have the type of text generated by predictions using Multinomial Naive Bayes.

This is the code:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
dataset = pd.read_csv("Test.csv", encoding='latin-1')

clf = MultinomialNB()
cv = CountVectorizer()


for row in dataset:
    text= row['Text']
    data = cv.transform([text]).toarray()
    output = clf.predict(data)
    dataset['Type']=dataset[output]
```

This is my error:

```
text= row['Text']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: We don't know what these variables are or what the error is. Try making a small running program that demonstrates the problem (including a sample data set) and post the traceback message.

Comment: Hello, @tdelaney, I edited my question, hope I'm more explicit now.

Comment: Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method used to iterate through the rows of the data frame is incorrect. So here

`for row in dataset:`

Only returns the 1st row , which usually contains all the column names which are normally strings. So when we do:
`text= row['Text']`
It tries to extract the string at the index 'Text' and string indices can only be integers, hence the error.

```
eg: text= "abc"
>print(text[0]) #Output is 'a'. 
>print(text['abc']) #Error - string indices must be integers
```

So the correct way to iterate through rows and extract the required column's value would be:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    text= row["Text"]
```

For information about the iterrows function , refer here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html