# Error occurs when im trying to load the api results to the variable "data" it says string indices must be intergers

Tags: python

```
import requests
import json

input = input(" put you data here: ")
url = "https://breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com/"

querystring = {"func":"auto","term":input}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "cdc2ac9cf2msh13a3dv713de3c61p1185f5jsncd225a72c5e1"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)

data = str(json.loads(response.text))

print(' this is data value' + data)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full traceback of the exception you are getting.  Right now, looking at your question, it's not obvious what part of your code the exception is being thrown from.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
data = json.loads(response.text)
```

It will return a `data` dictionary. Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers) for more details.