# TypeError: string indices must be integers --> Python

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, text-files, file-handling

I wanted to create a python function which should read each
character of a text file and then count and display
the occurrence of alphabets E and T individually (including
small cases e and t too).

```
def test():
    f = open("poem.txt",'r')
    count = 0
    count1 =0
    try:
        line = f.readlines()
        for i in line:
            for x in line:
                if (i[x] in 'Ee'):
                    count+=1
                else:
                    if (i[x] in 'Tt'):
                        count1+=1
        print("E or e",count)
        print("T or t",count1)
    except EOFError:
        f.close()
test()
```

This is what I tried

And it gave :

```
File "/Users/ansusinha/Desktop/Tution/Untitled15.py", line 23, in test
    if (i[x] in 'Ee'):
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try printing out each variable and see what values they hold. Even better if you know how to use a debugger. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: `.readlines()` returns a `list` of `str`. `for` loops in `python` are very different from those in `C`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I seeing "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, f.readlines() does not read only line, it reads all lines.
Code should be like this

```
def test():
    f = open("poem.txt",'r')
    count = 0
    count1 =0
    try:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            for char_in_line in line:
                if (char_in_line in 'Ee'):
                    count+=1
                elif (char_in_line in 'Tt'):
                    count1+=1
        print("E or e",count)
        print("T or t",count1)
    except EOFError:
        f.close()
test()
```

If your poem.txt is this,

```
LaLaLa
I'm shoes.
Who are you?
```

Then i[x] should be like this i["LaLaLa"]

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the fact that Python strings come with a `.count()` method.

You can read the entire file with

```
file_as_string = f.read()
```

and then count occurrences of any substring with

```
amount_of_E = file_as_string.count('E')
```

Check out `str.count` in Python documentation.

With

```
amount_of_Ee = file_as_string.lower().count('e')
```

you count occurrences of both E and e and with

```
amount_of_Tt = file_as_string.lower().count('t')
```

you are done with counting using two lines of code.

---

In your own code you try to index a string with another string, but string indices must be integers.

With `for x in line:` you actually wanted `for x in i:` where then the `x` will be a single character of line `i` you could directly use in `if x in 'eE':`.

But there is no need for the loops at all as Python strings come with the `.count()` method, so just use it.