# Is there any way I can fix the error string indices must be integers?

Tags: string, graph, jupyter-notebook, dataset, data-science

I tried to make graphs for my csv dataset in Jupyter Notebook, using this line of code:

```
bank['marital'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie',autopct='%.2f') 
plt.show()
```

However, the system return, "string indices must be integers".

I have tried to use many different methods like changing the string to a number,... but nothing really worked

Comment: This may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers

Comment: Can you show us how you are populating the `bank` variable? Is it a dataframe? Is it a list ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce it and it worked fine. So it's not something wrong with the code itself.
I suggest experimenting with:

1. restart Jupyter Notebook
2. play with a tiny synthetic dataset
3. cut the real dataset till it works
4. attach failing dataset contents to the question

Attaching my results:

```
[input.csv]
name,smth
Maria,12
Anton,2
Maria,3
...

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
df['name'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie',autopct='%.2f')
```

[image]