# Why is looping over a dictionnary (made form a json) leading to an error?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am trying to learn python. In this context, I get a json, and get a specific value. However, I get the following error: "string indices must be integers, not "str"." for my last line, "`print(dollar["rate_float"])`"

I have seen other questions on the topic, such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers), but I am not able to apply it or really understand it.

My code is as follows:

```
import sys
import requests
import json

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Missing command-line argument")

# Check if the user is giving a parameter after the program name

elif sys.argv[1].isalpha():
    print("Comand-line argument is not a number")

# Check if the user is giving numbers

else:
    response = requests.get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")

# Get a json from coindesk

    data_store = response.json()

# Store the json in the variable "data_store"

    for dollar in data_store["bpi"]:

# Loop over the dictionary to pick the price in dollar
        
        print(dollar["rate_float"])
```

After adapting the code as follows, based on the comments, I get another error: "name "bpi" is not defined".

```
# Store the json in the variable "data_store"

    for dollar in data_store[bpi.values()]:

# Loop over the dictionary to pick the price in dollar

        print(dollar[rate_float.values()])
```

The Json is as follows:

```
{
  "time": {
    "updated": "Feb 27, 2024 20:16:10 UTC",
    "updatedISO": "2024-02-27T20:16:10+00:00",
    "updateduk": "Feb 27, 2024 at 20:16 GMT"
  },
  "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
  "chartName": "Bitcoin",
  "bpi": {
    "USD": {
      "code": "USD",
      "symbol": "&#36;",
      "rate": "57,197.495",
      "description": "United States Dollar",
      "rate_float": 57197.4947
    },
    "GBP": {
      "code": "GBP",
      "symbol": "&pound;",
      "rate": "45,108.976",
      "description": "British Pound Sterling",
      "rate_float": 45108.9758
    },
    "EUR": {
      "code": "EUR",
      "symbol": "&euro;",
      "rate": "52,744.155",
      "description": "Euro",
      "rate_float": 52744.1549
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which line is getting the error?

Comment: I am sorry I should have indicated the error. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: So we don't have to visit that site, you should include an example of the JSON in your question.

Comment: OK, I will add it, I am sorry.

Comment: `data_store["bpi"]` should be `data_store["bpi"].values()`. You're looping over the dictionary keys, not the values.

Comment: based on the error the value of "dollar" is a string not a dictionary. hence it has no attribute "rate_float". I would check the ALL the objects in data_store["bpi"] are actually dictionaries, 1 of them might have returned an empty string instead.

Comment: But I need to loop over the key, and then get values, no? I do not understand?

Comment: "bpi" is the dictionary, and it has a series of key value pair. In the exercise I am supposed to be doing, I am supposed to get the price.  Hence, I am trying to get the value of "rate_float"

Comment: @TomasMichel no, you don't *have* to do that. If you want to loop over the keys and values, you wante `for key, value in mydict.items()`, just doing `for x in mydict:` gives you the keys, which you could do if you then used the key to access the values, but you don't, instead the code seems to assume you are getting the values, because you do `dollar["rate_float"]`, but `dollar` is a key, a `str` object, which you should have noticed by doing any basic debugging.

Comment: Also, I realize this is a pedantic point -- but you aren't looping over a JSON. This question really has nothing to do with JSON, you are working with a `dict` (the dict was created from a JSON, but that isn't relevant to the question at all)

Comment: I was also going to suggest using `.items()`. But as you can see, the key is duplicated in the `code` key of the value, so it's redundant.

Comment: Ok I will adapt the question name to reflect this @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: it's really an ancillary point, the key thing is you need to realize what `dollar` actually is, it is a `str` object corresponding to the keys of the dict at `data_store["bpi"]`, just print it out to see

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I gave up on tilting at that terminology windmill years ago. The objects and the JSON are isomorphic, it's just not worth confusing the posters. The only time it matters is when someone fails to parse the JSON.

Comment: haaaaaaaaaaaa I think I just understood! I am trying to print out the "key" / the "string" of this key, with how I wrote Python right now. What I should do instead is print the value associated to this key.

Comment: OK but after changing the code, I get another error "name is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are looping through the dictionary the values passed into dollar are the keys of the dictionary not the values. Instead you want to use `data_store["bpi"].values()` since this will loop through the values which in your case are dictionarie, then you can use `dollar["rate_float"]`.

The code would be:

```
import sys
import requests
import json

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Missing command-line argument")

# Check if the user is giving a parameter after the program name

elif sys.argv[1].isalpha():
    print("Comand-line argument is not a number")

# Check if the user is giving numbers

else:
    response = requests.get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")

# Get a json from coindesk

    data_store = response.json()

# Store the json in the variable "data_store"

    for dollar in data_store["bpi"].values():

# Loop over the dictionary to pick the price in dollar
        
        print(dollar["rate_float"])
```

Comment: Many thanks ! This works! But then I do not understand why in the specific examples given in the course, the loop seems to be done on the key of the dictionary, without requiring the "values". I do not understand what I did not understand from the course. Why this difference?