# Exporting data from JSon

Tags: excel, maps, export

We are creating a map application that has a list view of the resultant set using JSON and jQuery and presenting the result to the user.  How can we give the user the ability to download the result as an Excel file/CSV file?

Comment: which server side. `PHP` or `ASP` or some else

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a web application...

1. **Convert** JSON to CSV
2. **Present** It as an HTTP response.

You mentioned JSON and jQuery. I assume this is being used on the client side? There are a number of utilities for making the JSON-to-CSV conversion depending on the language you would want to use. Here are some examples.

- [Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable)
- [PHP](http://www.danmandle.com/blog/json-to-csv-conversion-utility/)
- [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848480/convert-json-to-csv-using-python-idle)