# Python - JSON to CSV table?

Tags: python, json, csv

I was wondering how I could import a JSON file, and then save that to an ordered CSV file, with header row and the applicable data below.

Here's what the JSON file looks like:

```
 [
  {
    "firstName": "Nicolas Alexis Julio",
    "lastName": "N'Koulou N'Doubena",
    "nickname": "N. N'Koulou",
    "nationality": "Cameroon",
    "age": 24
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Alexandre Dimitri",
    "lastName": "Song-Billong",
    "nickname": "A. Song",
    "nationality": "Cameroon",
    "age": 26,
    etc. etc. + } ]
```

Note there are multiple 'keys' (firstName, lastName, nickname, etc.).  I would like to create a CSV file with those as the header, then the applicable info beneath in rows, with each row having a player's information.

Here's the script I have so far for Python:

```
import urllib2
import json
import csv

writefilerows = csv.writer(open('WCData_Rows.csv',"wb+"))


api_key = "xxxx"
url = "http://worldcup.kimonolabs.com/api/players?apikey=" + api_key + "&limit=1000"
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
readable_json = json.load(json_obj)
list_of_attributes = readable_json[0].keys()

print list_of_attributes


writefilerows.writerow(list_of_attributes)

for x in readable_json:
    writefilerows.writerow(x[list_of_attributes])
```

But when I run that, I get a "TypeError: unhashable type:'list'" error.  I am still learning Python (obviously I suppose).  I have looked around online (found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/convert-from-json-to-csv-using-python)) and can't seem to figure out how to do it without explicitly stating what key I want to print...I don't want to have to list each one individually...

Thank you for any help/ideas!  Please let me know if I can clarify or provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TypeError` is occuring because you are trying to index a dictionary, `x` with a list, `list_of_attributes` with `x[list_of_attributes]`.  This is not how python works. In this case you are iterating `readable_json` which appears it will return a dictionary with each iteration.  There is no need pull values out of this data in order to write them out.

The [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) should give you what your looking for.

```
import csv
[...]

def encode_dict(d, out_encoding="utf8"):    
    '''Encode dictionary to desired encoding, assumes incoming data in unicode'''
    encoded_d = {}
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        k = k.encode(out_encoding)
        v = unicode(v).encode(out_encoding)        
        encoded_d[k] = v
    return encoded_d

list_of_attributes = readable_json[0].keys()
# sort fields in desired order
list_of_attributes.sort()

with open('WCData_Rows.csv',"wb+") as csv_out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_out, fieldnames=list_of_attributes)
    writer.writeheader()
    for data in readable_json:
        writer.writerow(encode_dict(data))
```

*Note:* 
    This assumes that each entry in `readable_json` has the same fields.

Comment: Aha! I think that's it - however, I am getting the error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in posiiton 6: ordinal not in range(128)".  If I'm not mistaken, that's because the player's names have accents in them, and I have to let Python know that?  Do I need to use something like .encode('utf-8') somewhere?

Comment: do you know the encoding the JSON data is in?

Comment: I am not sure, but if you don't mind, you can see the JSON data here: http://www.kimonolabs.com/worldcup/explorer

Comment: character decoding/encoding is a pain, Joel has a good article on it if your interested.  This should work...

Comment: I am definitely interested, do you have a link?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `pandas` could do this - but I newer tried to read JSON

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json( ... )

df.to_csv( ... )
```

[pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

[pandas.io.json.read_json](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.read_json.html)

---

**EDIT:**

```
data = ''' [
  {
    "firstName": "Nicolas Alexis Julio",
    "lastName": "N'Koulou N'Doubena",
    "nickname": "N. N'Koulou",
    "nationality": "Cameroon",
    "age": 24
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Alexandre Dimitri",
    "lastName": "Song-Billong",
    "nickname": "A. Song",
    "nationality": "Cameroon",
    "age": 26,
  }
]'''

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json(data)

print df

df.to_csv('results.csv')
```

result:

```
   age             firstName            lastName nationality     nickname
0   24  Nicolas Alexis Julio  N'Koulou N'Doubena    Cameroon  N. N'Koulou
1   26     Alexandre Dimitri        Song-Billong    Cameroon      A. Song
```

With `pandas` you can save it in `csv`, `excel`, etc (and maybe even directly in database).

And you can do some operations on data in table and show it as graph.

Comment: I installed Pandas, but get an error when trying the above, "ImportError: No module named numpy".

Comment: pandas has a number of dependencies, it's best to install via `pip`

Comment: I haven't been able to use pip - I get some errors...but that's an issue for another thread altogether.  I will keep trying though, thanks!