# Python: JSON to CSV Unicode Encoding

Tags: python, json, csv, unicode, character-encoding

I have a JSON file with Tweets - most of them are in German. I'd like to convert this to a CSV file. I'm new to Python and have followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1872081/5238350). But an encoding problem hinders me from proceeding.

Here is my code to generate a CSV file from the JSON file:

```
import csv
import json

x="""[
    {
   "created_at": "Thu, 24 Jan 2013 23:59:58 +0000",
   "id": 294595428815622140,
   "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.tweetdeck.com&quot;&gt;TweetDeck&lt;/a&gt;",
   "text": "RT @marthadear: ich heule gerade, aber h\\u00f6rt blo\\u00df nicht auf! #aufschrei",
   "user": {
      "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3187103131/33d7b666c757b7c50b01342f05345210_normal.jpeg",
      "screen_name": "KatrinaR47"
   }
    }
]"""


x = json.loads(x)

f = csv.writer(open("test2.csv", "wb+"))

for x in x:
    f.writerow([x["created_at"], 
                x["id"], 
                x["source"], 
                x["text"],
                x["user"]["profile_image_url"],
                x["user"]["screen_name"]])
```

The error message I'm getting is the following

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-0096601ea1bd> in <module>()
     26                 x["text"],
     27                 x["user"]["profile_image_url"],
---> 28                 x["user"]["screen_name"]])
     29 

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So apparently the decoding doesn't work. I've tried to find a number of different solutions but so far I wasn't able to apply one successfully. 
Can you help me out?

Comment: Are you using Python2 or Python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try encode `x["text"]` before writing it (in line 26)
Like this:

```
f.writerow([x["created_at"], 
            x["id"], 
            x["source"], 
            x["text"].encode("utf-8"),
            x["user"]["profile_image_url"],
            x["user"]["screen_name"]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly. Any idea how I can decode the HTML elements like "&lt;" or "&quot;" in "source"?

Comment: use "html" library!
`import html`
`html.unescape(x["source"])`